# How can I get rid of something running on every new terminal session?

Tags: bash, rvm

I am using Lion.  I have an error that outputs on every new terminal session:

```
-bash: __rvm_add_to_path: command not found
```

It's an almost brand new user account.. RVM is installed on the other account on the machine.. ~/.bashrc & ~/.bash_profile are both blank.. the out put of env is:

```
TERM_PROGRAM=Apple_Terminal
SHELL=/bin/bash
TERM=xterm-256color
TMPDIR=/var/folders/ry/8zsyknmx7dj4_2zzvn1n71500000gn/T/
Apple_PubSub_Socket_Render=/tmp/launch-jsfKPw/Render
TERM_PROGRAM_VERSION=303
TERM_SESSION_ID=3EBC0F1A-9867-41E5-8873-75E84B9F712F
USER=incorvia
COMMAND_MODE=unix2003
SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/tmp/launch-ZQqgPj/Listeners
Apple_Ubiquity_Message=/tmp/launch-u3d1lp/Apple_Ubiquity_Message
__CF_USER_TEXT_ENCODING=0x1F5:0:0
PATH=/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11/bin:/usr/local/git/bin
PWD=/bin
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
HOME=/Users/incorvia
SHLVL=1
LOGNAME=incorvia
DISPLAY=/tmp/launch-0B0I8s/org.x:0
_=/usr/bin/env
```

I see nothing related to RVM here.. where else can I look?

=====

## /etc/bashrc

```
# System-wide .bashrc file for interactive bash(1) shells.
if [ -z "$PS1" ]; then
   return
fi

PS1='\h:\W \u\$ '
# Make bash check its window size after a process completes
shopt -s checkwinsize
# Tell the terminal about the working directory at each prompt.
if [ "$TERM_PROGRAM" == "Apple_Terminal" ] && [ -z "$INSIDE_EMACS" ]; then
    update_terminal_cwd() {
        # Identify the directory using a "file:" scheme URL,
        # including the host name to disambiguate local vs.
        # remote connections. Percent-escape spaces.
        local SEARCH=' '
        local REPLACE='%20'
        local PWD_URL="file://$HOSTNAME${PWD//$SEARCH/$REPLACE}"
        printf '\e]7;%s\a' "$PWD_URL"
    }
    PROMPT_COMMAND="update_terminal_cwd; $PROMPT_COMMAND"
fi
```

=========

Fixed...

In the bottom of my /etc/profile it was sourcing /etc/profile.d/rvm.sh

Don't know how that got there...

Comment: Have you looked at `/etc/bashrc`?

Comment: I added the output of my /etc/bashrc

Comment: Check [this link](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/view/6.3/postlfs/profile.html) for other places; `/etc/profile` perhaps? It's more likely to be a global config than a user-specific.

Comment: Thanks.. it was in /etc/profile.. it was sourcing /etc/profile.d/rvm.sh

Comment: :) Just a headsup - removing it from `/etc/profile` will possibly break things for the other user.

Comment: `~/.bashrc` and anything sourced by it.

Comment: I installed rails using RVM on Mountain Lion as a regular user and for all users. sudo to root has same error message. I am  curious  where __rvm_add_to_path is defined. My symptoms. 'brevard@mac-mini:~ $ sudo su - 
-sh: __rvm_add_to_path: command not found
root@mac-mini:~ # echo $PATH
/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin
root@mac-mini:~ # logout
brevard@mac-mini:~ $ echo $PATH
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin:/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/bin:/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin:/usr/local/rvm/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin'

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Bash loads a series of files during startup. A good overview of the bash startup process can be found [here](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/view/6.3/postlfs/profile.html).

Generally, the global settings, `/etc/profile`, `/etc/bashrc`, and the associated personalized settings, `~/.profile` and `~/.bashrc` are loaded, although that is slightly distribution-dependant (and on Mac OS X, for example, by default `/etc/profile` doesn't exist).

From the [RVM Installation](http://beginrescueend.com/rvm/install/)  page:

> Multi-User:
>
> The rvm function will be automatically configured for every user on the system if you install as root. This is accomplished by loading /etc/profile.d/rvm.sh on login. Most Linux distributions default to parsing /etc/profile which contains the logic to load all files residing in the /etc/profile.d/ directory. Once you have added the users you want to be able to use RVM to the rvm group, those users MUST log out and back in to gain rvm group membership because group memberships are only evaluated by the operating system at initial login time.

I'd guess that the other use has installed in `Multi-User` mode;
`/etc/profile` probably loads `/etc/profile.d/rvm.sh`.

To stop it being loaded, you could remove the `source RVM` line from `/etc/profile` - this will stop it being loaded for *all users*, though.

Answer (score 4):

For the account that had a working profile, I had the following .rvmrc:

```
root@sc-27617:~# cat .rvmrc 
export rvm_prefix="/usr/local/lib/sc"
export rvm_path="/usr/local/lib/sc/rvm"
```

To get the error to go away for my other accounts, I simply copied this file to the other accounts and fixed the permissions (chown johndoe:johndoe /home/johndoe/.rvmrc)...

Answer (score 1):

In Ubuntu 12.04, by default, the /etc/profile.d/rvm.sh will not be loaded when starting a new terminal. So every time, when starting a new termail, cmd as follows must be used to start rvm:

```
source /etc/profile.d/rvm.sh
```

And there are two ways to fix it:

1. open a new terminal-> right click and select Profiles->Profile Preferences->Title and Command->select "Run command as a login shell".
2. open a new terminal->run cmd as follows then the /etc/profile.d/rvm.sh will be auto loaded in a new terminal:

   echo '[[ -s "/etc/profile.d/rvm.sh" ]] && . "/etc/profile.d/rvm.sh" # Load RVM function' >> ~/.bashrc

As some explanation [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/40287/etc-profile-not-being-sourced) to say the 1st solution is not a nice one but the 2nd is suggested.

So in other way round, if you do not want the terminal to run something in a new terminal, you need to check whether the auto load is coursed by the two ways:

1. check whether the "Run command as a login shell" is selected and unselect it.
2. open the ~/.bashrc file ,find the lines related loading the function and delete it.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same file (/etc/profile.d/rvm.sh) from a previous rvm installation. Deleting that file worked for me as well.

For the sake of being thorough, logging out of the shell seems to be required.

Answer (score 0):

In your `/etc/profile` change the line:

`source /etc/profile.d/rvm.sh`

into:

```
if [ "${SHELL}" != "/bin/sh" ]; then
  source /etc/profile.d/rvm.sh
fi
```

**Why?**

In Mac OS X the default shell of superuser (`root`) is a POSIX shell, not a pure Bash. Adding such condition will disable `rvm` for (possibly) emerygency shell `/bin/sh`, used by system administrator. That is good. If you would like to install something using `root`'s account, you can always type `bash` and then `rvm …` in a command line.

Answer (score 0):

Debian 6.1 scans the /etc/profile.d/ file for all .sh files and includes them, so there's no listing for rvm in any of the profiles or .bashrc files anywhere.  Deleting rvm.sh from /etc/profile.d/ solves this.

Answer (score 0):

if you have ZSH or OH-MY-ZSH, then you need to remove source **/etc/profile.d/rvm.sh** from **/etc/zprofile**