# Permission denied when trying to install RVM?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bash, terminal

I renamed my Macbook home directory to "hmumin" from "macbookpro".

I then tried to install RVM using:

```
$ curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s
```

but I get an error:

```
mkdir: /Users/macbookpro/.rvm/src: Permission denied
```

Is this error from trying to install RVM in the previous home directory?

If I run:

```
open /Users/macbookpro
```

I get:

```
The file /Users/macbookpro does not exist.
```

Yet, if I run:

```
mkdir /Users/macbookpro
```

I get:

```
mkdir: /Users/macbookpro: Permission denied
```

It's pretty confusing, I just want to install RVM.

When I type RVM I also get this type of error:

```
cat: /Users/macbookpro/.rvm/VERSION: No such file or directory
Warning! PATH is not properly set up, '/Users/macbookpro/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-           p353@railstutorial_rails_4_0/bin' is not at first place,
     usually this is caused by shell initialization files - check them for 'PATH=...' entries,
     it might also help to re-add RVM to your dotfiles: 'rvm get stable --auto-dotfiles',
        to fix temporarily in this shell session run: 'rvm use ruby-2.0.0-
p353@railstutorial_rails_4_0'.
     -bash: /Users/macbookpro/.rvm/scripts/base: No such file or directory
     -bash: /Users/macbookpro/.rvm/scripts/help: No such file or directory
     hmumin:~ hmumin$
```

Comment: Please review this previous post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5253643/cannot-install-rvm-permission-denied-in-usr-local-rvm

Comment: already tried that post it was no help

Comment: Please take the time to format your question so it's readable. As is, it's really difficult because you're not using capitalization or creating paragraphs correctly. The easier it is for us to read, the easier it is for us to answer.

Comment: Was RVM installed on your system? when home dir name was "macbookpro"?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you have multiple problems, and they need to be addressed individually before you can successfully install RVM:

1. You can't rename your home directory and expect a machine to be happy. There are multiple places that track your home directory name, including the security system that maintains the user and group information. You need to check on "[Ask Different](https://apple.stackexchange.com/)" for how to correctly recover from this situation, and then how to correctly change your home directory as it is off-topic for Stack Exchange.
2. Carefully read the [instructions for RVM installation](http://rvm.io/rvm/install) at http://rvm.io/rvm/install. RVM is a very easy-to-install Ruby manager, however there are decisions you have to make up front, before you begin installing it. I'd strongly recommend you do the single-user installation, but, no matter which you choose, read the entire page first.