# mkdir: /admin.rvm/src: Permission denied when installing RVM

Tags: ruby, rvm, osx-mavericks

Trying like heck to install RVM on Mavericks OSX.

using

```
    \curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable --ruby
```

and getting back

```
    mkdir: /admin.rvm/src: Permission denied
```

Any help is appreciated... please....

Comment: What `pwd` command output is? It seems you try to install it from the root directory. Try `cd && \curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable --ruby`.

Comment: pwd is /Users/Adam (Adam is my home directory).
Tried the cd && and have the same output....

Answer (score -2):

The problem could be that you're not running the command with admin privileges. Try using `sudo`:

```
sudo \curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable --ruby
```

You'll then have to enter your password, and it should work. Good luck!

Also: http://xkcd.com/149/

Comment: I'm sorry. This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5253643/cannot-install-rvm-permission-denied-in-usr-local-rvm 

It says not to use sudo, my bad. Good luck!