# ExecJS and could not find a JavaScript runtime

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1, execjs, javascript

I'm trying to use the [Mongoid / Devise Rails 3.1 template](https://github.com/RailsApps/rails3-mongoid-devise) (*[Mongoid](http://mongoid.org/)* and *[Devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise)*), and I keep getting an error stating [ExecJS](http://rubygems.org/gems/execjs) cannot find a JavaScript runtime.  Fair enough when I didn't have any installed, but I've tried installing [Node.js](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nodejs), [Mustang](https://github.com/nu7hatch/mustang) and the [Ruby Racer](https://github.com/cowboyd/therubyracer), but nothing is working.

I could not find a JavaScript runtime. See [sstephenson/ExecJS](https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs) (GitHub) for a list of available runtimes (`ExecJS::RuntimeUnavailable`).

What do I need to do to get this working?

Comment: btw - I am using ubuntu karmic.

Comment: You should really consider changing the answer. The Node.js answer is not nearly as good as the execjs/rubyracer.

Comment: The rubyracer has other issues with it. Heroku no longer recommends including it in your Gemfile if you can avoid it. https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails-asset-pipeline#therubyracer I think that installing a proper Javascript runtime on Ubuntu is the correct answer to this question.

Answer (score 453, accepted):

### Ubuntu Users

I'm on Ubuntu 11.04 and had similar issues. [Installing Node.js](https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/Installing-Node.js-via-package-manager) fixed it.

As of Ubuntu 13.04 x64 you only need to run:

```
sudo apt-get install nodejs
```

This will solve the problem.

---

### CentOS/RedHat Users

```
sudo yum install nodejs
```

Comment: tried it. no luck.  I wonder if it is a rvm conflict or something.  Everything other people have suggested hasn't worked for me.

Comment: Okey, i got the error when i tried generating a model in rails 3.1.0rc2. Does generating models work for you? (this was before installing nodejs that fixed it)

Comment: You can try changing the Gemfile so it uses rails3.1.0rc2 instead of 3.1.0.rc1 and run bundle install

Comment: actually, i just reinstalled nodejs and it worked.  Not sure what I did before but yay!

Comment: gem 'execjs'
gem 'therubyracer'

it's a better solution than this one.

Comment: I'm on Ubuntu 11.10 running Ruby 1.9.2 on Rails 3.1.3 freshly installed through RVM.
I need both the **package nodejs** and the **gem execjs** to resolve the isse on my machine. 
I did not need the therubyracer gem, but the execjs _per se_ did not solve the problem, so I guess for me it was a mix from the above and below solutions. Hope this can help others...

Comment: Heroku is now [strongly discouraging](http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails31_heroku_cedar#troubleshooting) therubyracer due to memory use. I installed nodejs on my dev machine per this answer and took therubyracer out of my gemfile. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7092107/rails-3-1-error-could-not-find-a-javascript-runtime.

Comment: @dwaynemac I disagree. I'd rather the runtime exist as an OS library (as with Mac and Windows by default), rather than adding yet another gem to the dependancy list.

Comment: @WilliamDenniss but it **is** a dependency. having it as a gem ensures you'll have that installed in any server you deploy.

Comment: @dwaynemac, true, but a lot of existing projects (as well as a fresh project generated by rails) do not have this dependency in their `Gemfile` and it's pretty annoying to have to add `therubyracer` every time on your own.

Comment: I prefer the Gemfile solution as it allows the project to build without dependancies on system-wide libraries

Comment: @dwaynemac: To run the rails test suite, you need to have it installed manually. Within your own application, both ways are valid options.

Comment: It seems that therubyracer and execjs are causing problems with heroku deployment, unless there's something else that was modified that I missed. This is the preferred solution.

Comment: I hesitate to add ```therubyracer``` to my Gemfile as it causes issues with Windows.  I know I may be crazy to develop on Windows, but I have to for work.

Comment: Doing `sudo apt-get install nodejs` worked for me on 14.04, but I suspect it's because it also installed libv8. I feel like installing `therubyracer` should fail if you don't have libv8 installed, but it doesn't -- it acts like it succeeds.

Comment: It does not work with Rails 6 and Ubuntu 18.04, does anyone show me how to fix it?

Answer (score 446):

Just add [ExecJS](http://rubygems.org/gems/execjs) and the [Ruby Racer](https://github.com/cowboyd/therubyracer) in your gem file and run `bundle install` after.

```
gem 'execjs'

gem 'therubyracer'
```

Everything should be fine after.

Comment: This worked for me, rails 3.1rc4 and Ubuntu 11.04 (my first try with rails 3.1). I was trying to generate a scaffold when I got the error. Still pretty lame that rails 3.1 is "broken" out of the box.

Comment: Was deploying on Heroku and received that error. Once I added the new gem and deployed, I was golden.

Comment: For Rails 3.1 RC 6, you just need to specify `gem 'therubyracer'`

Comment: Is there anyway to have these gems included in the default Gemfile when a new application is created?

Comment: Works on Ubuntu 11.04, 11.10. Thanks. Easy solution, but like other comments say: Why this? Must we always do this now?

Comment: this is a better solution than installing node.js. If you're deploying to a remote server or sharing the app with other developers, having everyone install node.js is a lot more pain than just running bundle install, which they would be doing anyway.

Comment: As stated above, since the official release of rails 3.1, just adding the rubyracer gem is enough. Although we would have liked to add nothing in the final release ! Thanks to foo for the precision.

Comment: Heroku is now [strongly discouraging](http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails31_heroku_cedar#troubleshooting) therubyracer due to memory use. I installed nodejs on my dev machine (https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/Installing-Node.js-via-package-manager) and took therubyracer out of my gemfile. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7092107/rails-3-1-error-could-not-find-a-javascript-runtime.

Comment: I was having this problem with Sinatra. I tried installing nodejs and may have missed a step but I was still receiving the error. Installing the two gems worked quite well. If this is the case with your rails app I recommend putting therubyracer in your development group and putting your app on heroku's cedar stack.

Comment: @MarkBerry thanks! I removed therubyracer and installed nodejs and it also sped up my dev env. Sweet.

Comment: This seems to be causing problems with heroku deployment.

Answer (score 78):

In your Gem file, write

```
gem 'execjs'
gem 'therubyracer'
```

and then run

```
bundle install
```

Everything works fine for me :)

Comment: You don't need to add 'execjs'

Comment: Yes u r right in rails 3.2.1 you have to use only gem'therubyracer'

Comment: Thanks @manish nautiyal and @ Peter Mortensen. it works for me

Answer (score 48):

I had a similar problem: my Rails 3.1 app worked fine on Windows but got the same error as the OP when running on Linux.  The fix that worked for me on both platforms was to add the following to my `Gemfile`:

```
gem 'therubyracer', :platforms => :ruby
```

The trick is knowing that `:platforms => :ruby` actually means *only use this gem with "C Ruby (MRI) or Rubinius, but NOT Windows."*

Other possible values for `:platforms` are described in [the `bundler` man page](https://bundler.io/v2.2/man/gemfile.5.html#PLATFORMS).

FYI: Windows has a builtin JavaScript engine which `execjs` can locate.  On Linux there is not a builtin although there are several available that one can install.  `therubyracer` is one of them.  Others are listed in the `execjs` [README.md](https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs/blob/master/README.md).

Comment: Thanks, this one fixed it for me on Ubuntu Oneiric using rvm installation of ruby 1.9.3 and Rails 3.2.1

Comment: I ran into the error on a CentOS server with node.js installed.  This got me past it.  Thanks!

Comment: New man page for `bundler` gemfile: https://bundler.io/v2.2/man/gemfile.5.html#PLATFORMS

Answer (score 37):

Adding the following gem to my Gemfile solved the issue:

```
gem 'therubyracer'
```

Then bundle your new dependencies:

```
$ bundle install
```

Comment: also add gem 'execjs' in Gemfile

Comment: execjs is already included by rails now.  It was only also required during the release candidates.

Answer (score 17):

An alternative way is to just bundle without the gem group that contains the things you don't have.

So do:

```
bundle install --without assets
```

you don't have to modify the Gemfile at all, providing of course you are not doing asset chain stuff - which usually applies in non-development environments.  Bundle will remember your '--without' setting in the .bundle/config file.

Comment: Best Answer. Worked for rails version 3.2.3

Comment: This is great, and such a simple fix. The Heroku site says RubyRacer is no longer required (with Cedar stack) so I was puzzled over why suddenly my program wasn't running locally. This did the trick.

Answer (score 8):

Add following gems in your gem file

```
gem 'therubyracer'
gem 'execjs'
```

and run

```
bundle install
```

you are done :)

Answer (score 7):

For amazon linux(AMI):

```
sudo yum install nodejs npm --enablerepo=epel
```

Comment: Thanks, this should be in a higher level

Comment: this was essential to getting a capistrano deployment to work on AWS standard linux distro.

Answer (score 6):

I had this same error but only on my staging server not my production environment.  nodejs was already installed on both environments.

By typing:

```
which node
```

I found out that the node command was located in: /usr/bin/node on production 
but: /usr/local/bin/node in staging.

After creating a symlink on staging i.e. :

```
sudo ln -s /usr/local/bin/node /usr/bin/node
```

the application then worked in staging.

No muss no fuss.

Comment: works like charm!
A advice: I needed make symlink for `nodejs` also

Comment: BOOM. Still a great answer in 2021. Kudos. In my case, I had to simlink for NVM, but the process was the same.

Answer (score 4):

I used to add the [Ruby Racer](https://github.com/cowboyd/therubyracer) to the Gem file to fix it. But hey, [Node.js](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nodejs) works!

Comment: how do you add nodejs to the gemfile? I didn't find a nodejs gem.

Answer (score 4):

I installed `node` via [nvm](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm) and encountered this issue when deploying with Capistrano. Capistrano didn't load nvm automatically because it runs non-interactively.

To fix, simply move the lines that nvm adds to your `~/.bashrc` up to the top. The file will then look something like this:

```sh
export NVM_DIR="$HOME/.nvm"
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh"  # This loads nvm
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion"  # This loads nvm bash_completion

# If not running interactively, don't do anything
case $- in
    *i*) ;;
      *) return;;
esac
```

Answer (score 3):

Don't Use RubyRacer as it is bad on memory. Installing Node.js as suggested by some people here is a better idea.

This list of available runtimes that can be used by ExecJs Library also documents the use of Node.js

https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs

So, Node.js is not an overkill, and much better solution than using the RubyRacer.

Answer (score 2):

FYI, this fixed the problem for me... it's a pathing problem:
http://forums.freebsd.org/showthread.php?t=35539

Answer (score 1):

The answer on a Mac in 2022 is simply:

`brew install nodejs`

Then rerun `rails server`.

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue and mostly there are answers that acknowledge the issue but I wanted to contribute with the clear answer I wasn't able to find.

#### The issue

This issue happened on my server (vps) because I installed node with `nvm` and  this node version manager is loaded in the shell configuration file such as `.bashrc` if you use `bash` or inside `.zshrc` if you use `zsh`.

What happens when you load the shell configuration file (automatically at startup time of the shell) is that the `$PATH` variable, is enriched with the `nvm` path, such that also `node` is findable. This is important, because all the paths put inside the `PATH` variable is where the shell looks for commands.

###### Main point of the issue

Since Capistrano is a non-interactive command tool that runs via ssh, I don't think `zshrc` and hence `nvm` and hence `node` are loaded. Therefore the `node` command wouldn't be findable during capistrano deployment, even if it's installed.

#### My solution

In order to make node findable, I found the easiest solution to be to put the installed `node` version inside the original $PATH (that being the $PATH avaiable even without loading `.zshrc`). A good place to do that is `/usr/bin/`.

###### Step 1: find where is node currently

Therefore find where is your node installed:

```
which node
# /home/deploy/.nvm/versions/node/v16.15.1/bin/node
```

or

```
whereis node
# node: /home/deploy/.nvm/versions/node/v16.15.1/bin/node
```

###### Step 2: create symlink

Now create a soft link in `/usr/bin`

```
ln -s /home/deploy/.nvm/versions/node/v16.15.1/bin/node /usr/bin/
```

###### Step 3: verify symlink

Now if you run again `whereis node` it should print both paths.

```
whereis node
node: /usr/bin/node /home/deploy/.nvm/versions/node/v16.15.1/bin/node
```

If you run capistrano now, it should work without throwing `execjs` error.

#### How to update

if you update the installed `node` version throughout the lifetime of the project you need to remember to delete the symlink you created and reinstall it with the new `node` version installed.

#### Things I wouldn't do

- I would not install directly node on the server without a `node` version manager.
- I would not modify the code inside `execjs` because that library is working correctly
- I would not run v8 in ruby with `therubyracer`, which just adds unnecessary overhead.

These are just workarounds that do not understand and acknowledge the main issue, which I explained above.

#### Other reasons

Of course, this issue and solution are relevant if you have installed node with nvm (it's advisable to use nvm but beyond the scope of this question), and capistrano still doesn't find node.

However, there could be other issues as mentioned by others such as that `node` is not at all installed, or `execjs` gem is not installed.

Answer (score 0):

I started getting this problem when I started using rbenv with Ruby 1.9.3 where as my system ruby is 1.8.7. The gem is installed in both places but for some reason the rails script didn't pick it up. But adding the "execjs" and "therubyracer" to the Gemfile did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

In your gem file
Uncomment this line.

19 # gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby

And run
bundle install

You are ready to work. :)

Answer (score 0):

**Attempting to debug in RubyMine using Ubuntu 18.04, Ruby 2.6.*, Rails 5, & RubyMine 2019.1.1**, I ran into the same issue.

To resolve the issue, I uncommented the `mini_racer` line from my `Gemfile` and then ran `bundle`:

```rb
# See https://github.com/rails/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'mini_racer', platforms: :ruby
```

Change to:

```rb
# See https://github.com/rails/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
gem 'mini_racer', platforms: :ruby
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Rails 7 and the bootstrap 5.2.3 Gem. On production it runs in a Docker Container, based on Alpine Linux. For my case it was not enough to install nodejs and npm. I had to install yarn like this:

```
apk add --no-cache yarn
```

Only after that, the error message disappeared on production.