# Rails startup Issues in Ubuntu

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu

I've used rvm to install rails..no problems.

Created a new app successfully

Running bundle install without issues.

Although, trying to run any command further (rails s, rails g controller.., etc)

I'm getting this error

```
    /home/USER/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/execjs-1.2.9/lib/execjs              /runtimes.rb:47:in `autodetect': Could not find a JavaScript runtime. See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs for a list of available runtimes. (ExecJS::RuntimeUnavailable)
```

I'm assuming there's an issue with a gem but I'm really clueless on what happened and can't seem to find anything that addresses this issue

Comment: possible duplicate of [Rails 3.1 error - Could not find a JavaScript runtime?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7092107/rails-3-1-error-could-not-find-a-javascript-runtime)

Comment: You may want to add your name to the list of affected users on the launchpad bug report: https://bugs.launchpad.net/turnkeylinux/+bug/1084235

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the best experience with using therubyracer on Ubuntu / Xubuntu (this is the Google V8 runtime) and Node.js in Windows. So basically yes, just adding

```
gem 'therubyracer'
```

to your Gemfile and running bundle install is enough. Node.js is not required.

Also take a look at: https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs

Answer (score 8):

This happens when your ubuntu installation does not have a javascript runtime installed.

Try:

```
sudo apt-get install nodejs
```

Comment: This is a better solution than just monkey-patching by adding the ruby racer gem, which is known to use a lot of memory, and don't need be included in the latest Rails versions.

Answer (score 2):

Add this to your `Gemfile`

```
gem 'therubyracer'
```

then run `bundle install` and you should be good to go!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.

Gemfile ->

```
gem 'execjs'
gem 'rubytheracer'
```

bundle install

Comment: `execjs` is not needed, that is a standard dependency of Rails. The error is generated by `execjs`, so OP already has that.