# Fastest javascript runtime for RoR?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

Are there any known performance differences between the various javascript runtimes available for Rails, like therubyracer (probably not the fastest), v8, node.js etc, and if so, which can be considered as among the fastest of the lot?

Edit: Also, for most practical intents and purposes, how many real options are there actually? On further reading it seems that everything points back to v8..

Comment: Node.js is technically V8 (http://nodejs.org/ "Node.js is a platform built on Chrome's JavaScript runtime")

Answer (score 2):

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7092107/rails-3-1-error-could-not-find-a-javascript-runtime) suggests node.js as the code size of therubyracer was problematic. [The documentation](http://railsapps.github.com/installing-rails-3-1.html) only mentions node.js or therubyracer and nothing else so I am not sure what else is out there.