# installation of ruby on rails using railsinstaller for windows

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

i had downloaded package railsinstaller for windows and had successfully installed it.

After that i followed these steps and got that window of localhost:3000 running successfully.

But now when i again starts it following error(**in the image link**) comes.

http://tinypic.com/r/11ch4ix/6

what should i do to solve this??

**ruby -v** command was also applied and everything is installed properly.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try this first: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13216969/429758 If that doesn't work, try installing the `therubyracer` and `execjs` gems as explained in the other answers there. Or install `node.js`

Comment: thankyou soo much :) installed node.js and it worked fine :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ruby on Rails needs a Javascript runtime installed on your computer.

First you should try putting the ExecJS gem in comment again (in your gemfile.rb).

Else you could install NodeJS, as it contains a Javascript runtime (V8 - used by Chrome).

Good luck!