# fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git on every rails command but git commands works fine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, repository

I've got a problem with git and my rails project.

I have set up a github repository and successfully pushed four commits. Every git command i'm trying is working as expected (`git status, git add, git commit, git push` etc.). But each time I try to execute a rails command (e.g. `bundle show, bundle install, rails s, rails generate, rake test` etc.) I get following message in my console:

```
fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
```

Every time the message appears on three lines. Sometimes on six lines. The `.git` folder is in my project and I'm in the correct folder. all rails commands are working as expected. But this annoying message comes with each rails command. I cloned the repository into another folder and created another repository and pushed the code to that new repositiory. The error is in my new folder, too.

I reinitialized my existing Git repository with `git init` but that changed nothing.

When I set up a fresh rails project and push it into a new repository etc. there are no errors. What could be wrong with my project? Any idea, why this is happening and how to fix this?

I'm working with `ruby 1.9.3`, `rails 3.2.1` and `git 1.7.9`.

thx to @manojlds I could isolate the problem a little bit more.  It's the therubyracer gem. I don't know what exactly is the problem but because I'm on windows I use this special therubyracer gem: https://github.com/hiranpeiris/therubyracer_for_windows. So I will ask the developer of this special gem and will show him the bundler bug. Maybe he will know if it's a problem with his gem or with the bundler. The bundler has an updated pre release. But I can't install the prerelease on windows. So I have to wait and therefore I must live for now with this annoying messages. Or is there a way to disable these messages?

Here is my github issue: https://github.com/hiranpeiris/therubyracer_for_windows/issues/1

Comment: This looks like a bug in the commands you are using... They should _at least_ hide the error messages -- or not trigger them in the first place.

Comment: What do you mean with a bug in my commands? The commands I'm entering are the standard rails commands (e.g "bundle show"). Could you explain that a little further?

Comment: When I got this issue, I wasn't cd'd into the correct directory

Comment: Same here , the moment i cd to the correct directory , the error stopped coming , Thanks again for saving my time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a bug for Bundler, which could be related: https://github.com/carlhuda/bundler/issues/2039

Definitely not a problem with git or your git repo. Try updating bundler. ( not sure if the fix is in stable version yet )

Comment: thx to your comment I could isolate the problem a little bit more. I commented out all additional gems in my gemfile. The error was gone. Than I commented out all additional gems one by one. It's the therubyracer gem. I don't know what exactly is the problem but because I'm on windows I use this special therubyracer gem: https://github.com/hiranpeiris/therubyracer_for_windows.

Comment: So I will ask the developer of this special gem and will show him the bundler bug. Maybe he will know if it's a problem with his gem or with the bundler. The bundler has an updated pre release. But I can't install the prerelease on windows. So I have to wait and therefore I must live for now with this annoying messages. Or is there a way to disable these messages?

Answer (score 15):

Try running `git init` in

`RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/therubyracer-0.11.0beta1-x86-mingw32`.

It will initialize a new empty git repo there.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you are in the right directory when you run that command:

```
git tag
```

I had the same problem while installing node.js from git and found that I had to be in a subdirectory after downloading it for the tag versions to display.

For example, I ran this command to get node.js:

```
git clone https://github.com/joyent/node.git
```

... but then had to  `cd node` to be in the node subdirectory before the `git tag` command worked.

Answer (score -1):

The rubytheracer gem has lots of issues.

Switch to node or execjs to avoid them.

More at: [Rails - Could not find a JavaScript runtime?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7092107/rails-could-not-find-a-javascript-runtime)