# Heroku: Could not find libv8-3.15.11.1 in any of the sources

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, heroku

I know there are a lot of these questions on Github (I've looked through all of them), but none of the answers have worked for me.

I am getting the error "Could not find libv8-3.15.11.1 in any of the sources" when I try "git push heroku master."  I specify the version of libv8 in my Gemfile (with gem "libv8", "~> 3.11.8.13"), and I think this is reflected in my Gemfile.lock ("libv8 (3.11.8.13)").  I don't understand why it's looking for version 3.15.11.1 when I've specified 3.11.8.13.

I made sure all my changes to the Gemfiles were committed (when I do "git status", I get "nothing to commit (working directory clean)."

I also tried removing heroku and re-adding it (with "git remote rm heroku" and then "git push heroku master").

**Gemfile:**

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.2.8'

group :development do
    gem 'sqlite3'
end

# Bundle edge Rails instead:
# gem 'rails', :git => 'git://github.com/rails/rails.git'

gem 'json'

gem 'rmagick'

# Gems used only for assets and not required
# in production environments by default.
group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'

  # See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
  # gem 'therubyracer', :platforms => :ruby

  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
  gem "twitter-bootstrap-rails"
  gem "less-rails"
  gem 'jquery-fileupload-rails'
end

gem 'jquery-rails'

gem 'activeadmin'
gem "meta_search",    '>= 1.1.0.pre'

gem 'friendly_id'

gem 'gon'

gem 'formtastic'

gem 'js-routes'

gem "therubyracer"

gem "libv8", "~> 3.11.8.13"

gem 'carrierwave'

gem 'ckeditor_rails'

gem 'font-awesome-rails'

group :production do
    gem 'pg', '0.12.2'
end

# To use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '~> 3.0.0'

# To use Jbuilder templates for JSON
# gem 'jbuilder'

# Use unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Deploy with Capistrano
# gem 'capistrano'

# To use debugger
# gem 'ruby-debug'
```

**Gemfile.lock**

```
GEM
  remote: https://rubygems.org/
  specs:
    actionmailer (3.2.8)
      actionpack (= 3.2.8)
      mail (~> 2.4.4)
    actionpack (3.2.8)
      activemodel (= 3.2.8)
      activesupport (= 3.2.8)
      builder (~> 3.0.0)
      erubis (~> 2.7.0)
      journey (~> 1.0.4)
      rack (~> 1.4.0)
      rack-cache (~> 1.2)
      rack-test (~> 0.6.1)
      sprockets (~> 2.1.3)
    activeadmin (0.5.1)
      arbre (>= 1.0.1)
      bourbon (>= 1.0.0)
      devise (>= 1.1.2)
      fastercsv
      formtastic (>= 2.0.0)
      inherited_resources (>= 1.3.1)
      jquery-rails (>= 1.0.0)
      kaminari (>= 0.13.0)
      meta_search (>= 0.9.2)
      rails (>= 3.0.0)
      sass (>= 3.1.0)
    activemodel (3.2.8)
      activesupport (= 3.2.8)
      builder (~> 3.0.0)
    activerecord (3.2.8)
      activemodel (= 3.2.8)
      activesupport (= 3.2.8)
      arel (~> 3.0.2)
      tzinfo (~> 0.3.29)
    activeresource (3.2.8)
      activemodel (= 3.2.8)
      activesupport (= 3.2.8)
    activesupport (3.2.8)
      i18n (~> 0.6)
      multi_json (~> 1.0)
    arbre (1.0.1)
      activesupport (>= 3.0.0)
    arel (3.0.2)
    bcrypt-ruby (3.0.1)
    bourbon (3.1.1)
      sass (>= 3.2.0)
      thor
    builder (3.0.4)
    carrierwave (0.8.0)
      activemodel (>= 3.2.0)
      activesupport (>= 3.2.0)
    ckeditor_rails (4.0.1.1)
      railties (>= 3.0)
    coffee-rails (3.2.2)
      coffee-script (>= 2.2.0)
      railties (~> 3.2.0)
    coffee-script (2.2.0)
      coffee-script-source
      execjs
    coffee-script-source (1.4.0)
    commonjs (0.2.6)
    devise (2.2.3)
      bcrypt-ruby (~> 3.0)
      orm_adapter (~> 0.1)
      railties (~> 3.1)
      warden (~> 1.2.1)
    erubis (2.7.0)
    execjs (1.4.0)
      multi_json (~> 1.0)
    fastercsv (1.5.5)
    font-awesome-rails (3.0.2.0)
      railties (>= 3.1)
    formtastic (2.2.1)
      actionpack (>= 3.0)
    friendly_id (4.0.9)
    gon (4.0.2)
      actionpack (>= 2.3.0)
      json
    has_scope (0.5.1)
    hike (1.2.1)
    i18n (0.6.1)
    inherited_resources (1.3.1)
      has_scope (~> 0.5.0)
      responders (~> 0.6)
    journey (1.0.4)
    jquery-fileupload-rails (0.4.1)
      actionpack (>= 3.1)
      railties (>= 3.1)
    jquery-rails (2.2.1)
      railties (>= 3.0, < 5.0)
      thor (>= 0.14, < 2.0)
    js-routes (0.8.7)
      rails (>= 3.2)
    json (1.7.7)
    kaminari (0.14.1)
      actionpack (>= 3.0.0)
      activesupport (>= 3.0.0)
    less (2.2.2)
      commonjs (~> 0.2.6)
    less-rails (2.2.6)
      actionpack (>= 3.1)
      less (~> 2.2.0)
    libv8 (3.11.8.13)
    mail (2.4.4)
      i18n (>= 0.4.0)
      mime-types (~> 1.16)
      treetop (~> 1.4.8)
    meta_search (1.1.3)
      actionpack (~> 3.1)
      activerecord (~> 3.1)
      activesupport (~> 3.1)
      polyamorous (~> 0.5.0)
    mime-types (1.21)
    multi_json (1.6.1)
    orm_adapter (0.4.0)
    pg (0.12.2)
    polyamorous (0.5.0)
      activerecord (~> 3.0)
    polyglot (0.3.3)
    rack (1.4.5)
    rack-cache (1.2)
      rack (>= 0.4)
    rack-ssl (1.3.3)
      rack
    rack-test (0.6.2)
      rack (>= 1.0)
    rails (3.2.8)
      actionmailer (= 3.2.8)
      actionpack (= 3.2.8)
      activerecord (= 3.2.8)
      activeresource (= 3.2.8)
      activesupport (= 3.2.8)
      bundler (~> 1.0)
      railties (= 3.2.8)
    railties (3.2.8)
      actionpack (= 3.2.8)
      activesupport (= 3.2.8)
      rack-ssl (~> 1.3.2)
      rake (>= 0.8.7)
      rdoc (~> 3.4)
      thor (>= 0.14.6, < 2.0)
    rake (10.0.3)
    rdoc (3.12.1)
      json (~> 1.4)
    ref (1.0.2)
    responders (0.9.3)
      railties (~> 3.1)
    rmagick (2.13.2)
    sass (3.2.5)
    sass-rails (3.2.6)
      railties (~> 3.2.0)
      sass (>= 3.1.10)
      tilt (~> 1.3)
    sprockets (2.1.3)
      hike (~> 1.2)
      rack (~> 1.0)
      tilt (~> 1.1, != 1.3.0)
    sqlite3 (1.3.7)
    therubyracer (0.11.3)
      libv8 (~> 3.11.8.12)
      ref
    thor (0.17.0)
    tilt (1.3.3)
    treetop (1.4.12)
      polyglot
      polyglot (>= 0.3.1)
    twitter-bootstrap-rails (2.2.4)
      actionpack (>= 3.1)
      execjs
      railties (>= 3.1)
    tzinfo (0.3.35)
    uglifier (1.3.0)
      execjs (>= 0.3.0)
      multi_json (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.2)
    warden (1.2.1)
      rack (>= 1.0)

PLATFORMS
  ruby

DEPENDENCIES
  activeadmin
  carrierwave
  ckeditor_rails
  coffee-rails (~> 3.2.1)
  font-awesome-rails
  formtastic
  friendly_id
  gon
  jquery-fileupload-rails
  jquery-rails
  js-routes
  json
  less-rails
  libv8 (~> 3.11.8.13)
  meta_search (>= 1.1.0.pre)
  pg (= 0.12.2)
  rails (= 3.2.8)
  rmagick
  sass-rails (~> 3.2.3)
  sqlite3
  therubyracer
  twitter-bootstrap-rails
  uglifier (>= 1.0.3)
```

Answer (score 0):

According to this page:

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails3x-asset-pipeline-cedar

"therubyracer 
If you were previously using therubyracer or therubyracer-heroku, these gems are no longer     required and strongly discouraged as these gems use a very large amount of memory."

Consequently I removed these from my test application. I then installed node.js on by ubuntu local machine and runs fine as it does on heroku.

See this question too:
[Rails - Could not find a JavaScript runtime?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7092107/rails-3-1-error-could-not-find-a-javascript-runtime)

Comment: thanks for your help.  even though I removed therubyracer and libv8 from my gemfile, I'm still getting the error "Could not find libv8-3.15.11.1 in any of the sources"  I checked that they also don't appear in the Gemfile.lock.

Comment: As far as I understand, you would only get that error if bundler is attempting to find a package and install it. If you have removed it from the Gemfile then it should not go look for it.