# How to get Ruby on Rails running, and start a server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm running Ruby on rails, and am almost there!  I go to execute the command

```
rails server
```

And it complains about Javascript runtime issues.
Below is just one example.

```
/home/cameron/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/execjs-1.4.0/lib/execjs/runtimes.rb:51:in `autodetect': Could not find a JavaScript runtime. See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs for a list of available runtimes. (ExecJS::RuntimeUnavailable)
    from /home/cameron/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/execjs-1.4.0/lib/execjs.rb:5:in `<module:ExecJS>'
```

So I went to this website like it said

```
https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs
```

How do you actually install one of these such as node.js to get the server to work?
Thanks so much for your help!  I'm looking forward to getting started with Ruby on Rails

Comment: possible duplicate of [ExecJS and could not find a JavaScript runtime](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6282307/execjs-and-could-not-find-a-javascript-runtime)

Comment: Your duplicate comment seems to be helpful.  I'm not using those systems, but did get the same error.  It also led me to another answer
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7092107/rails-could-not-find-a-javascript-runtime

which wanted me to use 'sudo apt-get install nodejs'

It is now working due to this :)  Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add

```
gem 'therubyracer'
```

to your `Gemfile`. Then run

```
bundle
```

The error occurs because you don't have JavaScript runtime environment, which is needed by `Asset Pipeline`.

Comment: I did this, and couldn't figure out how to restart my rails server.  It said control + C.  Tried that, and it didn't work.
It did this because I used control + Z.  I had to use `ps -aux` to find the pid , and then use `kill -9 pid` because `kill pid` was not working.

Comment: Thanks btw!, I really appreciate your help.  I am now up and running!! :)