# Proper "Rails" way to perform javascript on specific pages

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm attempting to run javascript on specific pages and my only solution seems like an anti-pattern. I have `controller.js` generated inside of `assets/javascripts/`. I'm using `gem 'jquery-turbolinks'` I have code resembling the following:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    //Initiate DataTables ect..
    }
)
```

This code is firing on every page So I added the following inside of it.

```
if ($('#page-specific_element').length > 0) {
    //Initiate Datatables ect.
}
```

My question being, is there a way to set rails to utilize only the javascript files necessary to a specific controller or is logic gating behind an element search the best solution?

Comment: I've tried adding   <%= javascript_include_tag params[:controller] %> to application.html.erb and removing //= require_tree . from application.js as part of a solution, but I run in to a need to add each "controller.js" to a pre-compile assets file, which seems to be going down the wrong road.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This is a pretty nice turbolinks specific solution:

```
<body data-controller="<%= controller.controller_name %>" data-action="<%= controller.action_name %>">
```

```js
// Instead of listening for document ready
$(document).on('users#show:loaded', function(){
    $('#logger').append('<li>Users Show action loaded</li>');
});

// Instead of listening for document ready
$(document).on('users:loaded', function(){
    $('#logger').append('<li>Some users controller method loaded</li>');
});

// Turbolinks fires "page:change" when it changes the page content.
// you could change this to just document ready if you are not using 
// turbolinks.
$(document).on("page:change", function(){
  var data = $('body').data();
  $(document).trigger(data.controller + ':loaded');
  $(document).trigger(data.controller + '#' + data.action + ':loaded');
});

// This is just for demonstration purposes...
$(document).trigger("page:change");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body data-controller="users" data-action="show">

  <ul id="logger"></ul>
</body>
```

You should note that if you are using Turbolinks that you'll have a long-running, persistent session with maintained state. Which means that if you add inline script tags or load additional javascript files in your views they will linger in the browsers memory.

You therefore might therefore want to cleanup whatever page specific event handlers you have created on `page:before-unload`.

Comment: Extremely elegant undiscovered Turbolinks jewel!

Comment: I have released a gem based on this pattern. https://github.com/maxcal/pagescript

Comment: @max , cannot install this gem for rails 5.1.3

Comment: @SyamsoulAzrien can you create an issue on github?

Answer (score 1):

There are *many* ways to do this. I'll describe one.

I use [this old gem](https://github.com/maccman/sprockets-commonjs) to wrap all my `.module.js` files in commonjs modules.

I then have a helper that writes something like the following to a `<script>` tag in the head of every HTML page.

```
<script>
  var App {
    pageModule: 'posts/create'
  };
</script>
```

`posts/create` is generated from a simplified mix of the current controller and action rendering the request.

I then have something like the following in my domready for my `application.js`.

```
try { App.pageModule = require(App.pageModule); } catch(e) { console.log('%c' + e, 'color:red; background-color:yellow'); }

if (_.isPlainObject(App.pageModule) && _.has(App.pageModule, 'initialize')) {
  App.pageModule.initialize();
}
```

Finally, I'll have a file like this which is specific to the `/posts/create` URL.

**app/assets/posts/create.module.js**

```
module.exports = {

  initialize: function() {
    // data-tables stuff here...
  }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for this solution. I found this similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3437585/best-way-to-add-page-specific-javascript-in-a-rails-3-app?rq=1 and it hadn't been addressed on there.