# Had to install node for a rails application and it's hogging CPU

Tags: ruby-on-rails, node.js, server

I have a Ruby on Rails 5.0 application. The server complained that it was missing a Javascript engine so I installed node.js.  Now, periodically, node will kill our server with CPU usage.  We use MongoDB, ElasticSearch, and Rails 5.0.

Any ideas how Rack or Rails, or Mongo or ES use node? And any ideas on how to troubleshoot.  We don't have any direct node calls in our code, it's all just infrastructure calls.

Comment: What do you mean with "The server complained that it was missing a Javascript engine"? Node.js is a bit more than just an engine.

Comment: you can take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27934178/what-is-therubyracer-or-libv8-for-in-a-rails-application