# "rails generate rspec:install" fails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I'm trying to run `rails generate rspec:install` but I get this error. I'm using ruby 2.0.0p353 and Rails 4.0.3.

The error is:

> /home/adminuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/execjs-2.0.2/lib/execjs/runtimes.rb:51:in `autodetect': Could not find a JavaScript runtime. See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs for a list of available runtimes. (ExecJS::RuntimeUnavailable)
>       from /home/adminuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/execjs-2.0.2/lib/execjs.rb:5:in`'
>       from /home/adminuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/execjs-2.0.2/lib/execjs.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
>       from /home/adminuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/uglifier-2.4.0/lib/uglifier.rb:3:in`require'
>       from /home/adminuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/uglifier-2.4.0/lib/uglifier.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
>       from /home/adminuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in`require'
>       from /home/adminuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `block (2 levels) in require'
>       from /home/adminuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:70:in`each'
>       from /home/adminuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:70:in `block in require'
>       from /home/adminuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:59:in`each'
>       from /home/adminuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:59:in `require'
>       from /home/adminuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler.rb:132:in`require'
>       from /home/adminuser/Desktop/667-workspace/assignment_3/config/application.rb:12:in `<top (required)>'
>       from /home/adminuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/railties-4.0.3/lib/rails/commands.rb:43:in`require'
>       from /home/adminuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/railties-4.0.3/lib/rails/commands.rb:43:in `<top (required)>'
>       from bin/rails:4:in`require'
>       from bin/rails:4:in `'

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7092107/rails-could-not-find-a-javascript-runtime

Comment: thank you. did not see this when i searched for same issue

Comment: @sevenseacat It's not people do not want to read it, it's just sometimes the error message carry concepts unfamiliar to programmer new to the field. It's part of the learning process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to install either [therubyracer](https://rubygems.org/gems/therubyracer) or [nodejs](http://nodejs.org/) in order to run rails generators. I prefer nodejs, cause it can be used in other cases such as [bower](http://bower.io/) or [npm](https://www.npmjs.org/)

Answer (score 2):

Just as the error suggest, you need a runtime(interpreter) for JavaScript on your local machine (no, those in browser wont do).

You can achieve this by installing gems such as therubyracer or run command like 'sudo apt-get install nodejs' just for their dependency

Answer (score 1):

Just add the runtimes in your project

```
# Gemfile
gem 'therubyracer'
```