# i am getting this error while running rails server command,please tell me how can i solve this?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/execjs-2.2.2/lib/execjs/run
times.rb:51:in `autodetect': Could not find a JavaScript runtime. See https://gi
thub.com/sstephenson/execjs for a list of available runtimes. (ExecJS::RuntimeUn
available)
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/execjs-2.2.2/l
ib/execjs.rb:5:in `<module:ExecJS>'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/execjs-2.2.2/l
ib/execjs.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/uglifier-2.6.0
/lib/uglifier.rb:3:in `require'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/uglifier-2.6.0
/lib/uglifier.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.3.5/
lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `require'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.3.5/
lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `block (2 levels) in require'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.3.5/
lib/bundler/runtime.rb:70:in `each'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.3.5/
lib/bundler/runtime.rb:70:in `block in require'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.3.5/
lib/bundler/runtime.rb:59:in `each'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.3.5/
lib/bundler/runtime.rb:59:in `require'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.3.5/
lib/bundler.rb:132:in `require'
        from c:/Sites/project/railgirl/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (require
d)>'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0
/lib/rails/commands.rb:76:in `require'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0
/lib/rails/commands.rb:76:in `block in <top (required)>'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0
/lib/rails/commands.rb:73:in `tap'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0
/lib/rails/commands.rb:73:in `<top (required)>'
        from bin/rails:4:in `require'
        from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

Comment: As you are using `Windows`, check this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13216969/2767755).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set it up quickly (without any concerns about gem code size, etc), put this in your Gemfile:

```
gem 'therubyracer'
```

Then run

```
bundle install
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because you have no Javascript Runtime installed on Windows.
This is required for things like ExecJS, TheRubyRacer and what not.

These gems will not compile properly on Windows unless you have a JS Runtime.
I recommend using the gem ***therubyracer*** and have the GoogleV8 Javascript engine installed on Windows:

https://developers.google.com/v8/build

You'll need to compile it yourself and make it available in your PATH.

Answer (score 0):

Put in your gemfile

gem 'therubyracer',  platforms: :ruby