# Trying to add bootstrap to rails. Need to install nodejs?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I am following a tutorial to install bootstrap on my rails application. 
I've been following this tutorial 
http://www.gotealeaf.com/blog/integrating-rails-and-bootstrap-part-1

Thought I run into this error, when I change my application.css to application.css.sass.

```
Current ExecJS runtime does't support ES5. Please install node.js.
  (in C:/Users/DanielH/Desktop/RotairApp/RubyDev/rotairapp/app/assets/stylesheets/application.css.sass)
Extracted source (around line #9):
6
7
8
9
10
11
12

   </style>

    <title>Rotair</title>
     <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
     <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
     <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
   </head>
```

The application css file now looks like

```
 @import "bootstrap-sprockets"
 @import "bootstrap"
```

Do I really need to install node.js?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a CDN too.
Just putt a CDN css file and JS links and you don't have to install anything.

here is the link to the files.
http://www.bootstrapcdn.com/

Comment: Ill take a look and get back

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is that if you want your application to serve Javascript, you need a javascript runtime. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7092107/rails-could-not-find-a-javascript-runtime) previous SO question. Basically Bootstrap does a lot of jQuery/JS wizardry to make things like modals work, so you have to have a JS runtime or bootstrap will not work.

You could use:

```
gem 'therubyracer'
gem 'execjs'
```

Or

```
node.js
```

I've generally had better luck with node.

Yes, you can use the CDN without the JS runtime, but you don't get the SASS variables, and can customize it.

Answer (score 0):

Installing nodeJS is all you nedd... Just restart twice... or more... Until the problem will solved itself.
That worked for me.