# How test a Rails app in a browser

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, browser, server

I used Fedora 21 in VirtualBox to create a rails app.
I have installed Ruby, Rails, rubygem, and bundle ($ bundle install) for my rails app.
However, when I go to http://localhost:3000/, there is an error...
When I run this command :

```
$ rails server
```

There is an error : Could not find a Javascript runtime

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Well, does it say what you should install to have a javascript runtime?

Comment: Try `bundle exec rails s`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

run bundle `exec rails server` if it still there try this

```
yum -y install nodejs
```

or look [at this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7092107/rails-could-not-find-a-javascript-runtime)

Comment: Thank you very much !! I can test my app in a browser !!