# ubuntu 16.04 rails 5 passenger nginx, node.js don't work as javascript runtime

Tags: ruby-on-rails, node.js, ubuntu, nginx, passenger

Hy there,
I'm working ours and don't find the solution.

When I'm starting rails 5 with puma on ubuntu 16.04 in development mode, everything works fine, node.js works as JavaScript runtime.

But when im starting the same application with nginx and passenger in production (precomiled with RAILS_ENV=production) I become the message:
"Message from application: There was an error while trying to load the gem 'uglifier'.
Gem Load Error is: Could not find a JavaScript runtime."

I know that I can use the gem 'therubyracer' but for some reasons I don't want.

Do somebody has an idea why node.js don't work with nginx and passenger.

Thanks ahead for every suggestion!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7092107/rails-could-not-find-a-javascript-runtime?

Comment: Are you sure is nodejs that is working? Have you deleted the `gem 'therubyracer'` from the Gemfile? What is the responso for `node --version`?

Comment: node --version => 4.2.6 and gem 'rubyracer' is in Gemfile commented. When running bundle list gem 'rubyracer' is not listed.