# Ruby Rake - Error

Tags: ruby, rake, migrate

I am using vmware and trying to run rake db:migrate for getting the database tables. I am getting this error.

```
ubuntu@ubuntu-VirtualBox:~/hw-acceptance-unit-test-cycle/rottenpotatoes$ bundle exec rake db:migrate
rake aborted!
Bundler::GemRequireError: There was an error while trying to load the gem 'coffee-rails'.
Gem Load Error is: Could not find a JavaScript runtime. See     https://github.com/rails/execjs for a list of available runtimes.
Backtrace for gem load error is:
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/execjs-2.7.0/lib/execjs/runtimes.rb:58:in `   autodetect'
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/execjs-2.7.0/lib/execjs.rb:5:in `<module:ExecJS>'
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/execjs-2.7.0/lib/execjs.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/coffee-script-2.4.1/lib/coffee_script.rb:1:in `require'
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/coffee-script-2.4.1/lib/coffee_script.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/coffee-script-2.4.1/lib/coffee-script.rb:1:in `require'
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/coffee-script-2.4.1/lib/coffee-script.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/coffee-rails-4.1.1/lib/coffee-rails.rb:1:in `require'
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/coffee-rails-4.1.1/lib/coffee-rails.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.13.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:91:in `require'
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.13.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:91:in `block (2 levels) in require'
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.13.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:86:in `each'
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.13.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:86:in `block in require'
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.13.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:75:in `each'
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.13.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:75:in `require'
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.13.6/lib/bundler.rb:106:in `require'
/home/ubuntu/hw-acceptance-unit-test-cycle/rottenpotatoes/config/application.rb:12:in `<top (required)>'
/home/ubuntu/hw-acceptance-unit-test-cycle/rottenpotatoes/Rakefile:5:in `require'
/home/ubuntu/hw-acceptance-unit-test-cycle/rottenpotatoes/Rakefile:5:in `<top (required)>'
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-11.2.2/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:28:in `load'
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-11.2.2/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:28:in `load_rakefile'
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-11.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:686:in `raw_load_rakefile'
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-11.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:96:in `block in load_rakefile'
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-11.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:178:in `standard_exception_handling'
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-11.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:95:in `load_rakefile'
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-11.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:79:in `block in run'
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-11.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:178:in `standard_exception_handling'
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-11.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:77:in `run'
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-11.2.2/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/bin/rake:23:in `load'
/usr/local/bin/rake:23:in `<main>'
Bundler Error Backtrace:
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.13.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:94:in `rescue in block (2 levels) in require'
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.13.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:90:in `block (2 levels) in require'
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.13.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:86:in `each'
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.13.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:86:in `block in require'
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.13.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:75:in `each'
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.13.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:75:in `require'
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.13.6/lib/bundler.rb:106:in `require'
/home/ubuntu/hw-acceptance-unit-test-cycle/rottenpotatoes/config/application.rb:12:in `<top (required)>'
/home/ubuntu/hw-acceptance-unit-test-cycle/rottenpotatoes/Rakefile:5:in `require'
/home/ubuntu/hw-acceptance-unit-test-cycle/rottenpotatoes/Rakefile:5:in `<top (required)>'
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-11.2.2/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'
ExecJS::RuntimeUnavailable: Could not find a JavaScript runtime. See    https://github.com/rails/execjs for a list of available runtimes.
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/execjs-2.7.0/lib/execjs/runtimes.rb:58:in `autodetect'
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/execjs-2.7.0/lib/execjs.rb:5:in `<module:ExecJS>'
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/execjs-2.7.0/lib/execjs.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/coffee-script-2.4.1/lib/coffee_script.rb:1:in `require'
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/coffee-script-2.4.1/lib/coffee_script.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/coffee-script-2.4.1/lib/coffee-script.rb:1:in `require'
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/coffee-script-2.4.1/lib/coffee-script.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/coffee-rails-4.1.1/lib/coffee-rails.rb:1:in `require'
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/coffee-rails-4.1.1/lib/coffee-rails.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.13.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:91:in `require'
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.13.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:91:in `block (2 levels) in require'
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.13.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:86:in `each'
```

/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.13.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:86:in `block in require'
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.13.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:75:in`each'
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.13.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:75:in `require'
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.13.6/lib/bundler.rb:106:in`require'
/home/ubuntu/hw-acceptance-unit-test-cycle/rottenpotatoes/config/application.rb:12:in `<top (required)>'
/home/ubuntu/hw-acceptance-unit-test-cycle/rottenpotatoes/Rakefile:5:in`require'
/home/ubuntu/hw-acceptance-unit-test-cycle/rottenpotatoes/Rakefile:5:in `<top (required)>'
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-11.2.2/exe/rake:27:in`'
(See full trace by running task with --trace)

What is the problem?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rails - Could not find a JavaScript runtime?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7092107/rails-could-not-find-a-javascript-runtime)

Answer (score 2):

If you are on Linux then run:

```
sudo apt-get install nodejs
```

On Mac:

```
brew install node
```

and then run bundle and try to migrate. Must work.
Also you shall be more attentive to the search on Stackoverflow for not to duplicate same topics.
[Rails - Could not find a JavaScript runtime?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7092107/rails-could-not-find-a-javascript-runtime)