# Failed to run project on ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5

I have copied a project from other system. Installed all the dependencies and trying to run the project. And there comes an error:

```
$ rails server
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/execjs-2.7.0/lib/execjs/runtimes.rb:58:in `autodetect': Could not find a JavaScript runtime. See https://github.com/rails/execjs for a list of available runtimes. (ExecJS::RuntimeUnavailable)
from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/execjs-2.7.0/lib/execjs.rb:5:in `<module:ExecJS>'
from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/execjs-2.7.0/lib/execjs.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/uglifier-3.0.3/lib/uglifier.rb:5:in `require'
from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/uglifier-3.0.3/lib/uglifier.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `require'
from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `block (2 levels) in require'
from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/bundler/runtime.rb:70:in `each'
from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/bundler/runtime.rb:70:in `block in require'
from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/bundler/runtime.rb:59:in `each'
from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/bundler/runtime.rb:59:in `require'
from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/bundler.rb:132:in `require'
from /var/www/html/psr-activity/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:88:in `require'
from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:88:in `block in server'
from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:85:in `tap'
from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:85:in `server'
from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:49:in `run_command!'
from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in `<top (required)>'
from /var/www/html/psr-activity/bin/rails:9:in `require'
from /var/www/html/psr-activity/bin/rails:9:in `<top (required)>'
from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/spring-2.0.0/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `load'
from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/spring-2.0.0/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `call'
from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/spring-2.0.0/lib/spring/client/command.rb:7:in `call'
from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/spring-2.0.0/lib/spring/client.rb:30:in `run'
from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/spring-2.0.0/bin/spring:49:in `<top (required)>'
from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/spring-2.0.0/lib/spring/binstub.rb:31:in `load'
from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/spring-2.0.0/lib/spring/binstub.rb:31:in `<top (required)>'
from /usr/local/lib/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
from /usr/local/lib/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
from /var/www/html/psr-activity/bin/spring:14:in `<top (required)>'
from bin/rails:3:in `load'
from bin/rails:3:in `<main>'
```

What may be the issue?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer helps me a lot.. Thanks @Michael Durrant [Run time environment problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7092107/rails-could-not-find-a-javascript-runtime)

Installed nodejs and worked absolutely fine..

Answer (score 0):

You can install NodeJs

Or better to uncomment the line

```
#gem 'mini_racer', platforms: :ruby
```

in Gemfile file, so rails will install V8 as a runtime-js.