# Rails' link_to method: GETing when it should DELETE

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, http-verbs

I'm following Michael Hartl's Rails Tutorial, and for some reason the following code:

```
<%= link_to 'delete', user, :method => :delete, :confirm => "You sure?",
                                :title => "Delete #{user.name}" %>
```

Issues a GET request (as I verified by checking the rails server log).  I also verified that the following line is in my application view:

```
<%= javascript_include_tag :all %>
```

One thing I didn't quite understand, and it's probably the source of my problem: where is the "delete" method defined?  I verified in [Hartl's source code](https://github.com/railstutorial/sample_app/blob/master/app/controllers/users_controller.rb) that he defines a "destroy" method in the controller, not "delete".  But even if I change the link_to to :method => :destroy, it just issues a GET.

I'm using Rails 3.1.  Any tips?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Most browsers don't actually support the DELETE verb, so Rails fakes it by modifying the HTML it generates. Rails tacks on a HTML5 attribute called `data-method` and sets it to `"delete"`.  So when a user clicks on the link, it is actually issued as a `GET` request, but the `data-method` attribute allows for some Rails magic and means your routing code should recognize it as a DELETE request.

**edit:**

You can test it yourself in the console. Run `bundle exec rails c` to get into the console, and look at the HTML that this generates:

```
helper.link_to "delete", "foobar/delete", :method => 'delete'
```

The HTML should look like this:

```
<a href="foobar/delete" data-method="delete" rel="nofollow">delete</a>
```

Comment: Thanks, Jergason!  This is the HTML that Rails generates for my "delete" -- <a href="/users/1" data-confirm="You sure?" data-method="delete" rel="nofollow" title="Delete Jared Clement">delete</a>  -- everything looks okay, yet when I click this link doesn't delete.  I'm using Chrome and typically have no issues with Javascript.  Any idea where I could look for the problem?

Comment: What does your `routes.rb` file look like?

Comment: Mine is here:
https://github.com/koggit/global2local-interpret/blob/master/config/routes.rb  


Hartl's is here:
https://github.com/railstutorial/sample_app/blob/master/config/routes.rb


It looks okay by comparison, though I don't yet understand the routes very well.

Comment: Can you tell if your UsersController#destroy method is firing when that link is clicked? Stick a print line in or something?

Comment: Thanks for your continued help, Jergason.  UserControler#destroy is not firing.  I may have located the issue:  `Served asset /all.js - 404 Not Found`.  It's trying to GET `/assets/all.js`, which doesn't exist.  I've Googled for info about this file but didn't come up with much.  Any tips for search terms to learn more about all.js in this context?

Comment: It seems like the Rails UJS stuff is not being included. If you are on Rails 3.1, then you may have some weirdness going on with your asset pipeline. I am not too familiar with that, but you should make sure your assets are being compiled correctly. You could try changing the include tag to `javascript_include_tag :defaults` to see if that helps.

Comment: Thanks-- your response helped me find the keywords to find this post, which has a solution -- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7281907/rails-3-1-issue-with-javascript-include-tag-in-application-html-erb -- unfortunately, despite working, it's unclear as to **why** this solution.  Oh well.  :)  Thanks again!

Comment: The button_to solution below was the best way around it for me!

Answer (score 80):

Also check that this is in your application.js:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
```

Apparently I had the jquery without the jquery_ujs and I had the same problem until I added that.

**Note** that you may need to add these lines above any import statements within application.js.

Answer (score 22):

You should use the following code

```
<%= button_to "delete", @user_current, :method => "delete" %>
```

It will solve the problem or add this line //= require jquery_ujs to application.js and use:

```
 <%= link_to 'delete', user, :method => :delete, data: {:confirm => "You sure?" } ,
                            :title => "Delete #{user.name}" %>
```

Comment: If you don't want to include JQuery, switching `link_to` > `button_to` will fix this issue, I believe.

Comment: I agree. If you want to use link_to, add jquery_ujs to application.js

Answer (score 6):

As browsers don't support the `DELETE` verb, Rails creates a workaround for this problem by simulating a `DELETE` request through a standard `GET` or `POST`. The way `method: :delete` works is with a JavaScript handler for all links with `data-method="delete"` which modifies the request so Rails
processes it as a *DELETE*. This JavaScript handler is provided by the `jquery_ujs` library.

There are several things that could have gone wrong:

1. Make sure you have both `jquery` and `jquery_ujs` included in your `application.js`. Without both nothing will process the data attributes.
2. Make sure the link in question really has the `method: :delete` option specified.
3. Make sure for some reason you haven't stopped the event propagation of the link in question, like so for example:

```js
$( 'a' ).click( function( event ) {
    event.stopPropagation()
})
```

As this would prevent the `jquery_ujs` handlers from being executed and the request will never be modified and will remain just a standard GET.

Answer (score 2):

I faced the same problem with Michael's tutorial. The `data-method="delete"` actually works as expected - it does call the destroy action in the controller. The reason it tries to `GET` (and eventually fail) is the following:

You'll notice that one of the `before_filter`'s in the controller is set to `signed_in_user`, and in `session_helper.rb`, you'll notice that `signed_in_user` calls `store_location` (private method), which updates `session[:return_to]` to the current URL.

So, back in your controller's destroy action, it tries to `redirect_back_or` which results in `GET current_url`. I modified the `signed_in_user` helper to only call `store_location` when user is not signed in already.

Answer (score 1):

On rails 5 :

Have the same problem, all 'DELETE' posts were compromised, affecting my crud pages AND devise signout... to solve the problem all I had to do was :

//= require rails-ujs

Answer (score 0):

All we need is add the below line of code

```
//= require jquery_ujs
```

It seems like a bug:))

Answer (score 0):

You want to do this in Rails 6+:

```
 link_to(
  'Delete Me',
   some_controller_path(model),
   data: { method: :delete }
 )
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `button_to` instead of `link_to`.