# Destroy action in a Rails 3.0 app with jquery mobile is producing a routing error

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, jquery-mobile

I'm using jquery mobile in a rails 3.0 app. I am getting a routing error when attempting to delete an item from a user's list. The code and error message are as follows.

index.mobile.erb:

```
<% @items.each do |i| %>
   ...
   <div data-role="button">
      <%= link_to 'Delete', i, :confirm => 'Are you sure?', :method => :delete %>
   </div>
<% end %>
```

routes file:

```
resources :items, :except => [:show]
```

rake routes:

```
DELETE /items/:id(.:format)            {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"items"}
```

error message:

```
Started GET "/items/2" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-02-26 13:31:37 -0500
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches "/items/2"):
```

What am I missing?

Thanks!

UPDATE - Firebug:
@http://localhost:3000/javascripts/jquery-1.6.1.js?1310343332:641 @http://localhost:3000/javascripts/jquery.mobile-1.0.1.js?1329380575:2737 @http://localhost:3000/javascripts/jquery.mobile-1.0.1.js?1329380575:3030 @http://localhost:3000/javascripts/jquery.mobile-1.0.1.js?1329380575:3393 @http://localhost:3000/javascripts/jquery-1.6.1.js?1310343332:2926 @http://localhost:3000/javascripts/jquery-1.6.1.js?1310343332:2560
jquery...0343332 (line 641)
"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://localhost:3000/items/2"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like the problem you're having is the same as mentioned @ [Rails' link_to method: GETing when it should DELETE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7465919/rails-link-to-method-geting-when-it-should-delete).

Can you paste rest of the request parameters (chrome developer console or firebug)? Have to see if rails is trying to do magic to accomodate the HTTP delete verb.

Comment: Firebug output is at the bottom of the question now. Thanks.