# Simple routing in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, link-to

I'm trying to destroy a link from a User Show view.

So from `/users/1`,

I want to access `destroy` action in `teacher_student_links` controller.

The first attempt:

```
<%= link_to 'destroy', :controller => "teacher_student_links", :action => "destroy", :id => @user.id %>
```

This fails because it routes to "show" action in the specified controller. **So first question: why does it point to the "show" action instead of "destroy?"** I tried to enclose the above with parenthesis, and got a meaningless error as well.

The second attempt:

in *config/routes.rb*

```
match '/bye_teacher' => 'teacher_student_links#destroy'
```

*view*

```
<%= link_to 'destroy', '/bye_teacher', :user_id => @user.id %>
```

also tried,

```
<%= link_to 'destroy', '/bye_teacher', :user_id => @user %>
```

Both lines correctly direct to the specified controller and action, but the parameter is not passed in. (can't find the user without an ID error)

second question: **am I passing in the variable in a wrong way in this case?**

It's little embarrassing to ask these two questions, but I wanted to know the reasons behind these problems.

UPDATE:

```
<%= link_to 'destroy', teacher_student_links_path(:user_id => @user), :method => :delete %>
```

gives

No route matches [DELETE] "/teacher_student_links"

```
<%= link_to 'destroy', teacher_student_links_path(@user), :method => :delete %>
```

gives

```
No route matches [DELETE] "/teacher_student_links.1"
```

... so I ran

`rake routes` and I got

`DELETE /teacher_student_links/:id(.:format)            teacher_student_links#destroy`

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7465919/rails-link-to-method-geting-when-it-should-delete

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are giving wrong path

```
<%= link_to 'destroy', teacher_student_links_path(@user), :method => :delete %>
```

should be like this:

```
<%= link_to 'destroy', teacher_student_link_path(@user), :method => :delete %>
```

When you run 'rake routes' then 1st column will tell you the path

Answer (score 1):

```
match "/bye_teacher/:id" => "teacher_student_links#destroy"


<%= link_to 'destroy', teacher_student_links_path(:id), 
:confirm => 'Are you sure you want to destroy this teacher?', :method => :delete %>
```

This should also work in the view:

```
<%= link_to 'Destroy', :action => 'destroy', :id => @user.id, :method => :delete %>
```

[Rails Routing from the Outside In](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html)

Comment: In this case, you don't need to put the match line in the routes, right?

Comment: Probably. You can run `rake routes` from the command line to be sure the RESTful path exists.

Comment: your answer was actually what I tried the very first time. I ran into this error though: `No route matches [DELETE] "/teacher_student_links.1"` even when rake routes gives `DELETE /teacher_student_links/:id(.:format)            teacher_student_links#destroy` I am confused why the path directs to  `..links.1` instead of `..links/1`

Comment: @MaximusS yeah, your teacher_student_links_path isn't set up in routes. Does my second method work?

Comment: no. This is same as my first attempt, which is described in the question. :(

Comment: Odd. you're sure you added `:method => :delete`?

Comment: Yes.. I don't know why this is happening but that seems to direct me to show action: `The action 'show' could not be found for TeacherStudentLinksController`