# Rails Simple Routing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, link-to

I can't understand why this simple routing isn't working right  now.

The link below doesn't work: it gives `routing error No route matches [DELETE] "/questions"`

```
<%= link_to 'delete', @question, :method => :delete, :action => :destroy %>
```

`rake routes` shows

```
DELETE /questions/:id(.:format)                        questions#destroy
```

correctly.

Does anyone can find the reason for this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
<%= link_to 'delete', question_path(@question), :method => :delete, :confirm => "Are you sure?" %>
```

Comment: Your solution gives, `No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"questions", :id=>#<Question id: nil, body: nil, user_id: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>}` and the same problem has happened to me in post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14451785/simple-routing-in-rails

Comment: @Maximus S: That would be because your `@question` object is not set up correctly. Please show us how you're setting it up within your controller.

Comment: You can see from the error message that the question_id is nil. You need an id for that route to work.

Comment: @RyanBigg you were right. I was calling `@question` when I should've called `question`