# Link_to generates a GET in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

A rails 4 app. A simple question: why does this genereate a GET request?

```
   <%= link_to("fdsfds", some_delete_path, method: :delete, data: { confirm: "Are you sure fdsfds?" }) %>
```

routes:

```
delete '/some-path/some-path123' => 'controller123#method123', as :some_delete
```

All query libraries are included properly.

html:

```
<a data-confirm="Are you sure?" rel="nofollow" data-method="delete" href="/fdsfdsfds">dsfdsfds</a>
```

error:

```
No route matches [GET] "/fdsfdsfdss"
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rails' link\_to method: GETing when it should DELETE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7465919/rails-link-to-method-geting-when-it-should-delete)

Comment: @RustamA.Gasanov, it's not. Русик, не тупи ради бога.

Comment: Are you sure it generates a GET request? Post the HTML fragment that it is generated.

Comment: @SimoneCarletti, yes

Comment: Make sure you have JS running in your app.

Comment: This should generate a delete. As Simone mentioned, please post the output HTML.

Comment: @RustamA.Gasanov, я это я.

Comment: @SimoneCarletti, updated.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is good, but your javascript include is probably not. Check that your application.js is including the correct libraries.  What you may be missing is '**jquery_ujs**' which is what handles confirmation dialogs and non-Get requests.

Here's mine with query.

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require_tree .
```

Without the javascript library, your link will be a GET request.

Comment: It should still build the correct link looking at link_to docs, http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html (under Options)

Answer (score 0):

I realize this isn't an answer, but instead a "how do I go about debugging this?"

What does your inspector show? Does it show the request as a DELETE? If no, continue.

Add this to the very bottom of your routes path, update the link_to, and check your inspector if it sends a DELETE request?

controller:

`def d 
  abort
end`

routes:

`match '/d' => 'posts#d', :via => [:delete]`

view:

`<%= link_to 'delete', '/d', :method => :delete %>`

There may be some conflicting route, which while highly unlikely, there are a lot of moving parts which sometimes cause finicky errors.

If that doesn't answer your question, can you post your routes and view, and perhaps a screenshot of your inspector?

Answer (score 0):

If anyone comes here that uses the bootstrap (v4) gem and always ignored the `tether` warning in development: You actually need to add the tether gem as advised.

That error stops executing the current js file. If all js files are seperate (as they are in development) this doesn't stop the `data-method` js part getting executed. In production all js is concat into a single file and thus it won't execute the rest of the file which likely contains the `data-method` code.