# Delete link not working for my model

Tags: ruby-on-rails

My destroy action is not working, I am using Rails 4.x

My routes:

```
resources :subscription_users, only: [:new, :create, :destroy]
```

My view page:

```
<% @subscription_users.each do |user| %>
  <%= link_to "delete", admin_subscription_user_path(user), :method => :delete %>
<% end %>
```

controller:

```
def destroy
  ..
  ..
end
```

When I click on the link I get this error:

```
No route matches [GET] "/admin/subscription_users/9"
```

My view page layout has the following:

```
//= require jquery
// require jquery_ujs
// require turbolinks
//= require_tree ./bootstrap
```

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7465919/rails-link-to-method-geting-when-it-should-delete

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
//= require jquery_ujs
```

Writing this line in your js file instead of `// require jquery_ujs` most probably will solve your problem.

Doing this will include Rails unobtrusive scripting adapter for jQuery into resulting JS. Currently it is commented out.

In your case, it will hook up to the link and send proper request (HTTP DELETE) when you click it.