# No route matches [GET] "/users/sign_out" **Rails 5/Bootstrap 4**

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, bootstrap-4

I am running Rails 5 and updated Bootstrap to version 4 in an existing app which uses Devise.

Before updating Bootstrap, the routes were working fine. Now, when the user selects sign-out, they receive the following message:

No route matches [GET] "/users/sign_out"

Here is part of the header code:

```
  <% if current_user %>
  <a class=<%= link_to 'Classes', tracks_path %></a>
  <a class=<%= link_to 'Edit profile', edit_user_registration_path %></a>
  <a class=<%= link_to 'Sign out', destroy_user_session_path, method: :delete %></a>
```

And *Rake Routes* shows:

destroy_user_session DELETE /users/sign_out(.:format)      devise/sessions#destroy

Is there a reason that the change to Bootstrap 4 would trigger this error? I have followed all of the instructions on the Bootstrap repo for installation.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7465919/rails-link-to-method-geting-when-it-should-delete

Answer (score 2):

The problem is you're rendering your link tags *inside* the class attribute:

```
<a class=<%= link_to 'Sign out', destroy_user_session_path, method: :delete %></a>
```

So that results in malformed output which ignores that you specify `method: :delete`. This is what you're looking for:

```
<%= link_to "Sign out", destroy_user_session_path, 
    method: :delete, class: 'nav-link' %>
```