# Button to delete user not working , Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am building a simple admin page and I can't get a button to delete the user from the record and refresh the page. Confusingly, the button will make a **POST** request instead of a **DELETE** request so my "toggle_admin" function will trigger in my controller instead. I have the route set up correctly to handle a delete request so I am stumped.

**index.html.erb**

```
<th><%= button_to "Toggle", :method=> :post, params: {user_id: user.id}  %></th>
<th><%= button_to "Destroy", :method=> :delete, params: {user_id: user.id} %></th>
```

**pages_controller.rb**

```
  def toggle_admin()
    selected = User.find(params[:user_id])
    puts selected
    selected.admin = !selected.admin
    selected.save
    redirect_to "/pages/admin"
    flash[:success] = "User admin rights sucessfully toggled"
  end



 def destroy
    selected = User.find(params[:user_id])
    selected.destroy
    redirect_to "/pages/admin"
  end
```

**routes.rb**

```
 get '/pages/admin', to: "pages#index"
 post '/pages/admin', to: "pages#toggle_admin"
 delete '/pages/admin', to: "pages#destroy"
```

**Console (When clicking the button to destroy)**

```
    Started POST "/pages/admin?id=1&method=delete" for #### at 2022-09-19 14:55:06 -0700
    Processing by PagesController#toggle_admin as TURBO_STREAM
    Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"[FILTERED]", "id"=>"1", "method"=>"delete"}
    Completed 404 Not Found in 1ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms | Allocations: 933)
```

Comment: Hi, I have solved this issue using these resources:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7465919/rails-link-to-method-geting-when-it-should-delete
https://medium.com/praaveen/rails-link-to-method-geting-when-it-should-delete-34c5dea0fc8a

Answer (score 1):

To solve:

I needed to change the route to

```
delete '/pages/admin', to: "pages#destroy", :as => :user
```

And the button to:

```
<th><%= button_to "Destroy", user, :method => :delete, params: {user_id: user.id} %></th>
```

Comment: It's worth noting it's 2022 and the Ruby 1.9 style is well entrenched, so you can do, more succinctly, `method: :delete` and so on. You're already doing this for `params:`.