# Error when deleting microposts. For some reason the GET method is requested for https

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, model-view-controller, routes

Please understand that I am not familiar with English.

I am creating a sample application with Rails.
For some reason the following error occurs when I press the delete button on a micropost.
[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A5k75.png)

First, paste the route file.

```
config/routes.rb

Rails.application.routes.draw do
  root "static_pages#home"
  get '/help', to: "static_pages#help"
  get '/search', to: 'searchs#search'
  get '/signup', to: 'users#new'
  get    "/login",   to: "sessions#new"
  post   "/login",   to: "sessions#create"
  delete "/logout",  to: "sessions#destroy"
  get '/diary',  to: "static_pages#diary"
  resources :users
  resources :microposts,          only: [:create, :destroy]
end
```

Next is the post management page for microposts, including a delete button.

```
_microposts.html.erb


<li id="micropost-<%= micropost.id %>">
  <%= link_to gravatar_for(micropost.user, size: 50), micropost.user %>
  <span class="user">
   <%= link_to micropost.user.name, micropost.user %>
  </span>
  <span class="content">
   <%= micropost.content %>
   <% if micropost.image.attached? %>
      <%= image_tag micropost.image.variant(:display) %>
   <% end %>
  </span>
  <span class="timestamp">
    Posted <%= time_ago_in_words(micropost.created_at) %> ago.
    <% if current_user?(micropost.user) %>
      <%= link_to "delete", micropost, data: { "turbo-method": :delete,
                                                turbo_confirm: "You sure?" } %>
    <% end %>
  </span>
</li>
```

A micropost controller containing a destroy method.

```
app/controllers/micropost_controller.rb

class MicropostsController < ApplicationController

    before_action :logged_in_user, only: [:create, :destroy]
        before_action :correct_user,   only: :destroy

    def create
     @micropost = current_user.microposts.build(micropost_params)
         @micropost.image.attach(params[:micropost][:image])
          if @micropost.save
           flash[:success] = "Micropost created!"
           redirect_to diary_path
          else
           @feed_items = current_user.feed.paginate(page: params[:page])
           render 'static_pages/home', status: :unprocessable_entity
          end
    end
  
       def destroy
         @micropost.destroy
         flash[:success] = "Micropost deleted"
        if request.referrer.nil?
         redirect_to root_url, status: :see_other
        else
         redirect_to request.referrer, status: :see_other
        end
       end
    
     private

    def micropost_params
      params.require(:micropost).permit(:content, :image)
    end

    def correct_user
      @micropost = current_user.microposts.find_by(id: params[:id])
      redirect_to root_url, status: :see_other if @micropost.nil?
    end
  end
```

models

```
app/models/micropost.rb

class Micropost < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  has_one_attached :image do |attachable|
    attachable.variant :display, resize_to_limit: [500, 500]
  end
  default_scope -> { order(created_at: :desc) }
  validates :user_id, presence: true
  validates :content, presence: true, length: { maximum: 140 }
  validates :image,   content_type: { in: %w[image/jpeg image/gif image/png],
                                    message: "must be a valid image format" },
                                    size:         { less_than: 5.megabytes,
                                    message:   "should be less than 5MB" }
end
```

I found a similar question on this site.
The answer is "There is a flaw in JS. Please add this to your Gemfile or js file".

```
Gemfile


source "https://rubygems.org"
git_source(:github) { |repo| "https://github.com/#{repo}.git" }

gem "rails",                      "7.0.4"
gem "ransack"
gem "image_processing",           "1.12.2"
gem 'jquery-rails'                         < add this.
gem 'turbolinks'                           < add this.
gem "active_storage_validations", "0.9.8"
gem "bcrypt",                     "3.1.18"
gem "faker",                      "2.21.0"
gem "will_paginate",              "3.3.1"
gem "bootstrap-will_paginate",    "1.0.0"
gem "bootstrap-sass",             "3.4.1"
gem "sassc-rails",                "2.1.2"
gem "sprockets-rails",            "3.4.2"
gem "importmap-rails",            "1.1.0"
gem "turbo-rails",                "1.1.1"
gem "stimulus-rails",             "1.0.4"
gem "jbuilder",                   "2.11.5"
gem "puma",                       "5.6.4"
gem "bootsnap",                   "1.12.0", require: false

group :development, :test do
  gem "sqlite3", "1.4.2"
  gem "debug",   "1.5.0", platforms: %i[ mri mingw x64_mingw ]
  gem 'guard-rspec', require: false
  gem 'factory_bot_rails'
end

group :development do
  gem "web-console", "4.2.0"
end

group :test do
  gem "capybara",                 "3.37.1"
  gem "selenium-webdriver",       "4.2.0"
  gem "webdrivers",               "5.2.0"
  gem "rails-controller-testing", "1.0.5"
  gem "minitest",                 "5.15.0"
  gem "minitest-reporters",       "1.5.0"
  gem "guard",                    "2.18.0"
  gem "guard-minitest",           "2.4.6"
  gem 'rspec-rails'
  gem 'spring-commands-rspec'
  gem 'factory_bot_rails'
  gem 'database_cleaner'
  gem 'launchy'
end

group :production do
  gem "pg",         "1.3.5"
  gem "aws-sdk-s3", "1.114.0", require: false
end


# gem "tzinfo-data", platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]
gem "erb-formatter", "~> 0.4.1"

gem "dockerfile-rails", ">= 1.0", :group => :development
```

js file.

```
app/assets/config/manifest.js

//= link_tree ../images
//= link_directory ../stylesheets .css
//= link_tree ../../javascript .js
//= link_tree ../../../vendor/javascript .js

//= require jquery      *< add this.*
//= require jquery_ujs  *< add this.*
```

I followed this but the error did not go away.

I don't think the settings for routing, controllers, links, etc. are correct,
but are there any flaws?
Or is it still j Query?
By the way, I understand the grammar of javascript, but I'm an amateur.

Thank you for reading this far.
If you have any ideas, please comment or answer.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Your English is excellent. In the future, please copy and paste plaintext errors into your post. [Screenshots of plaintext are problematic](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/3784008) for many reasons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rails dropped the `jquery_rails` gem way back when Rails 5.1 came out in 2017. It has no place in modern applications. It was replaced by `rails_ujs` which had the same functionality minus the jQuery dependency up until Rails 7.

Rails 7 replaces both `rails_ujs` and Turbolinks with
[Turbo](https://turbo.hotwired.dev/). Turbo provides the same functionality as `rails_ujs` but the data attribute that the event handler attaches itself to is named `data-turbo-method` instead of `data-method`.

You're actually doing it correctly here even if the idiomatically correct call is:

```
<%= link_to "delete", micropost, data: { turbo_method: :delete, turbo_confirm: "You sure?" } %>
```

You can also use [`button_to`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v7.0.4.2/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-button_to) which works even without JS:

```
<%= button_to "delete", micropost, method: :delete, data: { turbo_confirm: "You sure?" } %>
```

### So why isn't it working?

There could be a lot of different reasons.

- Turbo isn't loaded on the page.
- A script error is preventing Turbo from working.
- There is a conflicting event handler on the page that is breaking the functionality provided by Turbo.
- [...]

Any of these will lead to the link doing what links naturally do and a GET request will be sent instead. Checking the browser console is your first step in debugging this.

See:

- https://guides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html#replacements-for-rails-ujs-functionality
- https://turbo.hotwired.dev/handbook/drive#performing-visits-with-a-different-method

Comment: thank you.
For the time being, I couldn't solve the JS and jQuery related parts no matter how hard I tried, so changing to button_to fixed it. Let's review the structure of the file once.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Rails 7+, the preferred way is to use a button:

```
<%= button_to "delete", micropost, method: :delete %>
```

It will render an HTML form which sends a POST request with a hidden `_method` attribute with 'delete' value. Rails will treat this as if it has a DELETE method. And there is no need to use Rails UJS or jQuery.

**NOTE** Do not use this one within another form (HTML forbids one form inside another).

Answer (score -1):

can you try

```
<%= link_to 'delete', YOUR_PATH, method: :delete %>
```

Otherwhise you should look this SO [Rails' link_to method: GETing when it should DELETE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7465919/rails-link-to-method-geting-when-it-should-delete)

Comment: thank you for contacting. 
I couldn't do it all, but should I show you all the JS related files?
Probably, the jquery file cannot be read properly, and the existing answers are all old versions of rails.