# ActionView::Template::Error in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I'm confused to at what is causing this error? I am able to run the application in production on my local machine and everything compiles without issue, however when on windows server 2012 it's causing an issue.

Any suggestions?

```
[2013-03-05 10:27:18] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=2008 port=3000
Connecting to database specified by database.yml
Started GET "/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-03-05 10:27:28 +0000
Processing by StaticController#home as HTML
  Rendered static/home.html.erb within layouts/application (108.0ms)
Compiled cloud.css  (1ms)  (pid 2008)
Compiled contact.css  (0ms)  (pid 2008)
Compiled footer.css  (0ms)  (pid 2008)
Compiled global.css  (1ms)  (pid 2008)
Compiled header.css  (0ms)  (pid 2008)
Compiled nav.css  (1ms)  (pid 2008)
Compiled news.css  (0ms)  (pid 2008)
Compiled ourteam.css  (0ms)  (pid 2008)
Compiled services.css  (0ms)  (pid 2008)
Compiled slider/nivo-slider.css  (0ms)  (pid 2008)
Compiled slider/themes/bar/bar.css  (0ms)  (pid 2008)
Compiled slider/themes/dark/dark.css  (1ms)  (pid 2008)
Compiled slider/themes/default/default.css  (0ms)  (pid 2008)
Compiled slider/themes/light/light.css  (0ms)  (pid 2008)
Compiled application.css  (287ms)  (pid 2008)
Compiled jquery.js  (6ms)  (pid 2008)
Compiled jquery_ujs.js  (1ms)  (pid 2008)
Compiled jquery.flip.min.js  (0ms)  (pid 2008)
Compiled jquery-1.8.3.js  (6ms)  (pid 2008)
Compiled jquery.flip.js  (1ms)  (pid 2008)
Compiled slider/jquery-1.9.0.min.js  (3ms)  (pid 2008)
Compiled slider/jquery.nivo.slider.js  (2ms)  (pid 2008)
Compiled application.js  (431ms)  (pid 2008)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 144851ms

ActionView::Template::Error (
  (in C:/inetpub/wwwroot/app/assets/javascripts/application.js)):
    4:     <title>Class Technology Solutions <%= content_for?(:title) ? '- ' + y
ield(:title) : "" %></title>
    5:     <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    6:     <%= stylesheet_link_tag "application" %>
    7:     <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
    8:     <%= csrf_meta_tag %>
    9:   </head>
    10:   <body>
  app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:7:in `_app_views_layouts_application_ht
ml_erb___324488381_53941380'
  app/controllers/static_controller.rb:12:in `home'
```

application.js:

```
// This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.js, which will include all the files
// listed below.
//
// Any JavaScript/Coffee file within this directory, lib/assets/javascripts, vendor/assets/javascripts,
// or vendor/assets/javascripts of plugins, if any, can be referenced here using a relative path.
//
// It's not advisable to add code directly here, but if you do, it'll appear at the bottom of the
// the compiled file.
//
// WARNING: THE FIRST BLANK LINE MARKS THE END OF WHAT'S TO BE PROCESSED, ANY BLANK LINE SHOULD
// GO AFTER THE REQUIRES BELOW.
//
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require jquery.flip.min
//= require_tree .
```

Comment: Can you post the content of `application.js` please. Also, why are you including both the development and minified versions of jQuery Flip?

Comment: Added, also thank you for noticing this, I am clueless when it comes to jQuery/Javascript etc. I am now using just the minified version.

Comment: Why do you include jquery.flip twice?

Comment: And why you don't include jquery.flip in application.js manifest file ?

Comment: I don't include it anymore, I took it out as advised by Robin Fisher. And I'm a newbie when it comes to Rails, so shall I include it like so..? //= require jquery.flip.min.js

Comment: Add `//= require jquery.flip.min` before the `require_tree` line and remove it from the `<%= javascript_include_tag %>` in your layout and report back.

Comment: I've done this and updated code, no changes.

Answer (score 0):

delete this line **//= require_tree .**

in    **app/assets/javascripts/application.js**

the same issue :

[Rails 3.1 issue with javascript_include_tag in application.html.erb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7281907/rails-3-1-issue-with-javascript-include-tag-in-application-html-erb)

Comment: Thank you, however this unfortunately does not work for me, I still get the same error.

However, commenting out <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %> works for me.