# Error in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I am trying to learn Ruby on rails following the "Agile Web Development with Rails" book.
In the book it says how to create a doc file for your project:

```
rails_apps> rails new dummy_app
rails_apps> cd dummy_app
dummy_app> rake doc:rails
```

but I get this error:

```
rake aborted!
Could not find a JavaScript runtime. See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs for a list of available runtimes.

(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

why? and how can i fix it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Rails 3.1 execjs and Could not find a JavaScript runtime](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6282307/rails-3-1-execjs-and-could-not-find-a-javascript-runtime)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to install a Javascript runtime. There are a few options listed in the URL in the error message (https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs). If you don't have a strong preference, I'd recommend [therubyracer](https://github.com/cowboyd/therubyracer) (Google V8).

Just add this to your `Gemfile`:

```
gem 'therubyracer', require: "v8"
```

and run

```
bundle install
```

Comment: Iget this : syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting $end
gem 'therubyracer', require: 'v8'

Comment: If you're using ruby < 1.9 use `:require => "v8"` instead