# ruby_threadptr_data_type error

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-debug, ruby-1.9.3

I'm starting up a new rails app with the latest version of rails (3.1.3).  Rails crashes when I try to start up the server. First I fixed [this bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6282307/rails-3-1-execjs-and-could-not-find-a-javascript-runtime), and now I'm getting this one

```
ruby-debug-base19-0.11.25/lib/ruby_debug.so: undefined symbol: ruby_threadptr_data_type
```

There's a discussion about this going on [here](http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issue/RUBY-9418), but I can't make enough sense of it to get things to work.

## UPDATE

I updated the version of ruby-debug

```
gem 'ruby-debug-base19x', '~> 0.11.30.pre4'
```

and have now moved on to this error

```
linecache19-0.5.12/lib/trace_nums19.so: undefined symbol: ruby_current_thread
```

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Ok, it turns out that both ruby-debug and linecache needed to be manually updated to the latest versions.  These lines in my gemfile did the trick

```
gem 'linecache19', :git => 'git://github.com/mark-moseley/linecache'
gem 'ruby-debug-base19x', '~> 0.11.30.pre4'
gem 'ruby-debug19'
```

To run specs, you need to run **bundle exec rspec -d spec**

Comment: this is the same answer as the one by @Jakob_Cosoroaba

Comment: @klaffenboeck - yeah, it is.  This one was here for about a week before he gave his answer. Not sure why he duplicated it.

Comment: Doesn't work. Still have the same problem. Tried with required, and without git and version definition. The same.

Comment: This worked great for me on Ruby 1.9.3-p0 and Rails 3.2.0.rc2.  Thanx!

Comment: Verified to be working with 1.9.3-p125 and OSX Lion.  Why this is so hard to keep in line I have no idea. *shakes fist*

Comment: @voxobscuro - yeah, when I posted this I never thought it would still be the right solution 5 months later.

Answer (score 4):

At last I found the problem. The debugger in RubyMine starts without bundle exec, so it doesn't use linecache19 from git. You need to install it manually.

Resolution of the problem found here: http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RUBY-9418?projectKey=RUBY

```
gem uninstall linecache19
gem uninstall ruby-debug-base19x
curl -OL http://rubyforge.org/frs/download.php/75414/linecache19-0.5.13.gem
gem install linecache19-0.5.13.gem
gem install ruby-debug-base19x –-pre
```

Make sure to uninstall all linecache19 and ruby-debug-base19x!

Answer (score 2):

The following lines worked for me:

```
gem 'linecache19'
gem 'ruby-debug-base19x'
gem 'ruby-debug19', :require => 'ruby-debug'
```

(Hat tip to declan. His comment didn't work for me, but it gave me the idea to add linecache19.)

Comment: I tried everything else as well and this was the only solution that solved my issue. For those updating to Ubuntu 12.04, ruby will be auto updated to 1.9.3p0.

Answer (score 0):

after trying all advise on stackoverflow, the following combination worked for me

```
gem 'linecache19', :git => 'git://github.com/mark-moseley/linecache'
gem 'ruby-debug-base19x', '~> 0.11.30.pre4'
gem 'ruby-debug19'
```

I'm running Rails 3.1.3 on Ruby 1.9.3-p0 with RVM

when I set `:require => 'ruby-debug'` the server would not start.

Answer (score -1):

It's repost from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8251349/ruby-threadptr-data-type-error)

I also ran into this, and found the solution in [Ruby 1.9.3 and ruby-debug](http://blog.wyeworks.com/2011/11/1/ruby-1-9-3-and-ruby-debug). You need to install not-yet-officially-released versions of ruby-debug-base19 and linecache19. The currently released versions indeed cause the exception you had.

Use [this gist](https://gist.github.com/1331533).

```
#To install ruby-debug on Ubuntu ruby-1.9.3 you need to download from http://rubyforge.org/frs/?group_id=8883

linecache19-0.5.13.gem 
ruby_core_source-0.1.5.gem 
ruby-debug19-0.11.6.gem 
ruby-debug-base19-0.11.26.gem

#Then in your console

export RVM_SRC=/your/path/to/ruby-1.9.3
# Note, your source path should be something like /home/user/.rvm/src/ruby-1.9.3-p0

gem install archive-tar-minitar
gem install ruby_core_source-0.1.5.gem -- --with-ruby-include=/$RVM_SRC
gem install linecache19-0.5.13.gem -- --with-ruby-include=/$RVM_SRC
gem install ruby-debug-base19-0.11.26.gem -- --with-ruby-include=/$RVM_SRC
gem install ruby-debug19-0.11.6.gem -- --with-ruby-include=/$RVM_SRC
```

I tried it and it's work!

This is solve of our problems.