# how do I get linecache19 0.5.12 to install under ruby-193-p125?

Tags: debugging, ubuntu, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I have a Rails app that has been running fine for months. The other day I went through the laundry list of upgrades in Ubuntu and installed them all. Suddenly, I can't start my dev server because of failures in linecache. I've read various threads on this topic:

[ruby_threadptr_data_type error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8251349/ruby-threadptr-data-type-error)

[Rails with ruby-debugger throw 'Symbol not found: _ruby_current_thread (LoadError)'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6438116/rails-with-ruby-debugger-throw-symbol-not-found-ruby-current-thread-loaderro/9267541#9267541)

http://isitruby19.com/linecache

http://antisnatchor.com/debugging_ruby_1.9.3p125

[Installing linecache19 for Ruby 1.9.2 via rvm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6650567/installing-linecache19-for-ruby-1-9-2-via-rvm)

Still, after spending hours on waiting for installs to fail, I can't get my rails dev server to start.

My versions look like this:

```
~/app> which ruby
/usr/share/ruby-rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/bin/ruby
~/app> which rvm
/usr/share/ruby-rvm/bin/rvm
~/app> rvm current
ruby-1.9.3-p125
~/app> ruby -v
ruby 1.9.3p125 (2012-02-16 revision 34643) [i686-linux]
~/app>
```

And here's what happens when I try to install the current version of ruby-debug:

```
~/app> gem install 'ruby-debug-base19x' 
Fetching: ruby-debug-base19x-0.11.29.gem (100%)
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing ruby-debug-base19x:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

        /usr/share/ruby-rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/bin/ruby extconf.rb
checking for rb_method_entry_t.body in method.h... no
checking for vm_core.h... no
/usr/share/ruby-rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/ruby_core_source-0.1.5/lib/ruby_core_source.rb:39: Use RbConfig instead of obsolete and deprecated Config.
checking for rb_method_entry_t.body in method.h... no
checking for vm_core.h... no
*** extconf.rb failed ***
```

And my gemfile (the relevant bit anyway):

```
group :development, :test do
  ...
  gem 'linecache19', :git => 'git://github.com/mark-moseley/linecache'
  gem 'ruby-debug-base19x' 
  gem 'ruby-debug19'

end
```

Anyone have an idea of what's actually going on here? I'm pretty stumped. I'm willing to start over from scratch if I need to. I just need to know the best way to go back to bare canvas and what to paint.

Comment: an off-topic vote? good lord, i don't know how much more programming specific this could be

Comment: I absolutely don't understand why this question is only getting negative votes. It's bizarre.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect that my RVM install got goofed up somehow, even though I used the instructions on the RVM site. I solved it with these two posts:

[Installed Ruby 1.9.3 with RVM but command line doesn't show ruby -v](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9056008/installed-ruby-1-9-3-with-rvm-but-command-line-doesnt-show-ruby-v/9056395#9056395)

http://blog.sudobits.com/2011/10/27/how-to-install-ruby-on-rails-in-ubuntu-11-10/