# ruby / rails `rescue in debug=': (RuntimeError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rbenv

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [ruby_threadptr_data_type error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8251349/ruby-threadptr-data-type-error)

I am new to Ruby / Rails, and having issues getting my environment setup on Ubuntu 12.04. I'm using rbenv (not rvm). Here is how i'm installing ruby:

```
# clone rbenv and the ruby-build plugin
git clone git://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv.git .rbenv
git clone git://github.com/sstephenson/ruby-build.git ~/.rbenv/plugins/ruby-build

# initialize rbenv
export PATH=~/.rbenv/bin:$PATH
rbenv init -

# install ruby 1.9.2
rbenv install 1.9.2-p320
rbenv rehash

# change ruby version to 1.9.2
rbenv global 1.9.2-p320
```

I am trying to run the following hello-world app:
  https://github.com/renderedtext/base-app

I am running the commands recommended on the website

```
bundle install
bundle exec rake db:setup db:test:prepare
bundle exec rake spec
bundle exec rake cucumber
```

It fails at `bundle exec rake spec` with the following error:

```
NOTICE:  CREATE TABLE will create implicit sequence "roles_id_seq" for serial column "roles.id"
NOTICE:  CREATE TABLE / PRIMARY KEY will create implicit index "roles_pkey" for table "roles"
NOTICE:  CREATE TABLE will create implicit sequence "users_id_seq" for serial column "users.id"
NOTICE:  CREATE TABLE / PRIMARY KEY will create implicit index "users_pkey" for table "users"
/home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/1.9.2-p320/bin/ruby -S rspec ./spec/models/role_spec.rb ./spec/models/user_spec.rb ./spec/controllers/admin/base_controller_spec.rb ./spec/controllers/admin/users_controller_spec.rb ./spec/controllers/pages_controller_spec.rb ./spec/helpers/pages_helper_spec.rb
No DRb server is running. Running in local process instead ...
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-2.10.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:422:in `rescue in debug=':  (RuntimeError)
**************************************************
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/ruby-debug-base19-0.11.25/lib/ruby_debug.so: undefined symbol: ruby_threadptr_data_type - /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/ruby-debug-base19-0.11.25/lib/ruby_debug.so

If you have it installed as a ruby gem, then you need to either require
'rubygems' or configure the RUBYOPT environment variable with the value
'rubygems'.

/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/ruby-debug-base19-0.11.25/lib/ruby-debug-base.rb:1:in `require'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/ruby-debug-base19-0.11.25/lib/ruby-debug-base.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/ruby-debug19-0.11.6/cli/ruby-debug.rb:5:in `require'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/ruby-debug19-0.11.6/cli/ruby-debug.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-2.10.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:408:in `require'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-2.10.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:408:in `debug='
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-2.10.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration_options.rb:20:in `block in configure'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-2.10.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration_options.rb:19:in `each'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-2.10.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration_options.rb:19:in `configure'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-2.10.1/lib/rspec/core/command_line.rb:21:in `run'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-2.10.1/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:66:in `rescue in run'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-2.10.1/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:62:in `run'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-2.10.1/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:10:in `block in autorun'
**************************************************
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-2.10.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:407:in `debug='
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-2.10.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration_options.rb:20:in `block in configure'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-2.10.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration_options.rb:19:in `each'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-2.10.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration_options.rb:19:in `configure'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-2.10.1/lib/rspec/core/command_line.rb:21:in `run'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-2.10.1/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:66:in `rescue in run'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-2.10.1/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:62:in `run'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-2.10.1/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:10:in `block in autorun'
rake aborted!
/home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/1.9.2-p320/bin/ruby -S rspec ./spec/models/role_spec.rb ./spec/models/user_spec.rb ./spec/controllers/admin/base_controller_spec.rb ./spec/controllers/admin/users_controller_spec.rb ./spec/controllers/pages_controller_spec.rb ./spec/helpers/pages_helper_spec.rb failed

Tasks: TOP => spec
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

It is also important to note that the server seems to already have ruby 1.9.1 installed (presumably using apt-get) but I would like to use 1.9.2 which is why I installed rbenv.

As a side note, I've also tried using rbenv with 1.9.3 and get the same error.

I tried to research and apply answers from other stack overflow questions (like [ruby_threadptr_data_type error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8251349/ruby-threadptr-data-type-error)) but resulted in a segfault. Also, in my research most of the answers seemed to relate to rvm and 1.9.3 ... not rbenv and 1.9.2

Please help!

Comment: so that actually did the trick ... but now it has me wondering -- that project is forked by a 16 people ... is this issue specific to linux? or is the project just broken for everyone?

Comment: ruby-debug is outdated, I believe that using debugger is a better solution in a long run.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like rspec couldn't load ruby-debug. [Here's where it's happening](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-core/blob/2-10-maintenance/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb#L408) if you're curious. You probably forgot to add `require 'rubygems'` in your spec_helper.rb. Do so and let me know if this fixed it.

UPDATE:

Try removing `gem 'ruby-debug19'` from Gemfile and replacing it with `gem 'debugger'` then run `bundle` in console and try again. ruby-debug19 is not maintained so this probably the cause. [More about debugger](https://github.com/cldwalker/debugger). There's also link to ruby-debug19 installation instructions(if you feeling lucky).

Comment: He is using Ruby 1.9x so `require rubygems` is not needed.

Comment: hey Vadim, the specfile has requite 'rubygems': https://github.com/renderedtext/base-app/blob/master/spec/spec_helper.rb