# Rails 3 Coffee Handler Missing

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, coffeescript, passenger

Im using Ruby 1.9.3p0, Rails 3.1.2 with Apache and Passenger in Production. When I try to make a remote function, it throws me this error:

```
ActionView::MissingTemplate (Missing template video/loadVideo, application/loadVideo with
{:handlers=>[:erb, :builder], :formats=>[:js, "application/ecmascript", "application/x-
ecmascript", :html, :text, :js, :css, :ics, :csv, :xml, :rss, :atom, :yaml, 
:multipart_form, :url_encoded_form, :json], :locale=>[:en, :en]}. Searched in
```

As you can see, there is no handler for **:coffee**, that's the reason why is not processing the file **video/loadVideo.js.coffee**; I run the command **rake assets:precompile** but nothing changes.

The Gemfile
    source 'http://rubygems.org'

```
gem 'rails', '3.1.2'

# Bundle edge Rails instead:
# gem 'rails',     :git => 'git://github.com/rails/rails.git'

gem 'will_paginate', '~> 3.0'
gem "bcrypt-ruby", :require => "bcrypt"
gem 'mysql'

#Problems in Debian, the error was:
#Could not find a JavaScript runtime. See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs #for a list of available runtimes. (ExecJS::RuntimeUnavailable)
#Solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6282307/rails-3-1-execjs-and-could-not-find-a-javascript-runtime
gem 'execjs'
gem 'therubyracer'

# Gems used only for assets and not required
# in production environments by default.
group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.1.5.rc.2'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.1.1'
  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
end

gem 'jquery-rails'

# To use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '~> 3.0.0'

# Use unicorn as the web server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Deploy with Capistrano
# gem 'capistrano'

# To use debugger
# gem 'ruby-debug19', :require => 'ruby-debug'

group :test do
  # Pretty printed test output
  gem 'turn', '0.8.2', :require => false
end
```

Comment: Having the coffee-rails gem inside there doesn't mean that it provides a coffee handler.

Comment: Please, do not use camel case for templates. Rails convention is to use underscores. `loadVideo` template should be `load_video`.

Answer (score 13):

Change your Gemfile (move coffee-rails gem outside the assets group) or change your application.rb settings - for instance

```
if defined?(Bundler)
  # If you precompile assets before deploying to production, use this line
  # Bundler.require(*Rails.groups(:assets => %w(development test)))
  # If you want your assets lazily compiled in production, use this line
  Bundler.require(:default, :assets, Rails.env)
end
```

In development environment application by default loads all of gems from `:default, :development, :test, :assets` groups. Coffee handler comes from `coffee-rails` gem, so you have to load it.

Comment: I hit the same thing and it worked once I moved the coffee gem out of the assets namespace.  I guess most people only use coffeescript in assets and not in views... The weird thing is, it worked in development mode when the Gem was only specified in the assets block.