# Can't start Rails Server on Ubuntu looking for Runtime even if its already installed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

After several tries of fixing this matter(installed rubyracer, updated gems) and I still can't run the server. I'm on freshly installed ubuntu 12.04, using ruby 2.0.0-p247 and rails 4.0.0

```
/home/janharold/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/execjs-1.4.0/lib/execjs/runtimes.rb:51:in `autodetect': Could not find a JavaScript runtime. See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs for a list of available runtimes. (ExecJS::RuntimeUnavailable)
from /home/janharold/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/execjs-1.4.0/lib/execjs.rb:5:in `<module:ExecJS>'
from /home/janharold/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/execjs-1.4.0/lib/execjs.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
from /home/janharold/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/uglifier-2.1.2/lib/uglifier.rb:3:in `require'
from /home/janharold/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/uglifier-2.1.2/lib/uglifier.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
from /home/janharold/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `require'
from /home/janharold/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `block (2 levels) in require'
from /home/janharold/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:70:in `each'
from /home/janharold/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:70:in `block in require'
from /home/janharold/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:59:in `each'
from /home/janharold/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:59:in `require'
from /home/janharold/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler.rb:132:in `require'
from /home/janharold/GIT Repositories/treebook/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
from /home/janharold/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:76:in `require'
from /home/janharold/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:76:in `block in <top (required)>'
from /home/janharold/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:73:in `tap'
from /home/janharold/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:73:in `<top (required)>'
from bin/rails:4:in `require'
from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, by installing NodeJS independently, I managed to run the server without any problem.

Details at [execJs: 'Could not find a JavaScript runtime' but execjs AND therubyracer are in Gemfile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9202324/execjs-could-not-find-a-javascript-runtime-but-execjs-and-therubyracer-are-in)

Comment: This the best and fastest option. I always install NodeJS on each server or developer machine and NodeJS solves this javascript runtime issue everywhere. :)