# Rails 3.2.6 install on Centos6

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, centos, centos6

I did the following steps in order, but have issues running webrick

I have a centos 6 install

Step 1: 
http://blog.jeffcosta.com/2011/07/22/install-ruby-version-manager-rvm-on-centos-6/

Step 2:
server-world.info/en/note?os=CentOS_6&p=mysql

Step 3:
sudo install mysql -- --with-mysql-config=/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql_config
gem install -y mysql -- --with-mysql-config=/usr/bin/mysql_config

It installed all the gems without any issues.

But when I load webrick from the application which was created using 
 **rails new simple_cms -d mysql**

Result:
create
      create  README.rdoc 
      create  Rakefile 
      create  config.ru 
      create  .gitignore 
      create  Gemfile 
      create  app 
      create  app/assets/images/rails.png 
      create  app/assets/javascripts/application.js 
      create  app/assets/stylesheets/application.css 
      create  app/controllers/application_controller.rb 
      create  app/helpers/application_helper.rb 
      create  app/mailers 
      create  app/models 
      create  app/views/layouts/application.html.erb 
      create  app/mailers/.gitkeep 
      create  app/models/.gitkeep 
      create  config 
      create  config/routes.rb 
      create  config/application.rb 
      create  config/environment.rb 
      create  config/environments 
      create  config/environments/development.rb 
      create  config/environments/production.rb 
      create  config/environments/test.rb 
      create  config/initializers 
      create  config/initializers/backtrace_silencers.rb 
      create  config/initializers/inflections.rb 
      create  config/initializers/mime_types.rb 
      create  config/initializers/secret_token.rb 
      create  config/initializers/session_store.rb 
      create  config/initializers/wrap_parameters.rb 
      create  config/locales 
      create  config/locales/en.yml 
      create  config/boot.rb 
      create  config/database.yml 
      create  db 
      create  db/seeds.rb 
      create  doc 
      create  doc/README_FOR_APP 
      create  lib 
      create  lib/tasks 
      create  lib/tasks/.gitkeep 
      create  lib/assets 
      create  lib/assets/.gitkeep 
      create  log 
      create  log/.gitkeep 
      create  public 
      create  public/404.html 
      create  public/422.html 
      create  public/500.html 
      create  public/favicon.ico 
      create  public/index.html 
      create  public/robots.txt 
      create  script 
      create  script/rails 
      create  test/fixtures 
      create  test/fixtures/.gitkeep 
      create  test/functional 
      create  test/functional/.gitkeep 
      create  test/integration 
      create  test/integration/.gitkeep 
      create  test/unit 
      create  test/unit/.gitkeep 
      create  test/performance/browsing_test.rb 
      create  test/test_helper.rb 
      create  tmp/cache 
      create  tmp/cache/assets 
      create  vendor/assets/javascripts 
      create  vendor/assets/javascripts/.gitkeep 
      create  vendor/assets/stylesheets 
      create  vendor/assets/stylesheets/.gitkeep 
      create  vendor/plugins 
      create  vendor/plugins/.gitkeep 
         run  bundle install 
Fetching gem metadata from [https://rubygems.org/]. 
Could not load OpenSSL.
You must recompile Ruby with OpenSSL support or change the sources in your
Gemfile from 'https' to 'http'. Instructions for compiling with OpenSSL
using RVM are available at rvm.io/packages/openssl.

**I get the following error when running rails server:**

/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/execjs-1.4.0/lib/execjs/runtimes.rb:51:in `autodetect': Could not find a JavaScript runtime. See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs for a list of available runtimes. (ExecJS::RuntimeUnavailable) <br>
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/execjs-1.4.0/lib/execjs.rb:5:in`' 
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/execjs-1.4.0/lib/execjs.rb:4:in `<top (required)>' <br>
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/coffee-script-2.2.0/lib/coffee_script.rb:1:in`require' 
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/coffee-script-2.2.0/lib/coffee_script.rb:1:in `<top (required)>' <br>
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/coffee-script-2.2.0/lib/coffee-script.rb:1:in`require' 
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/coffee-script-2.2.0/lib/coffee-script.rb:1:in `<top (required)>' <br>
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/coffee-rails-3.2.2/lib/coffee-rails.rb:1:in`require' 
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/coffee-rails-3.2.2/lib/coffee-rails.rb:1:in `<top (required)>' <br>
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/bundler-1.1.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:68:in`require' 
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/bundler-1.1.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:68:in `block (2 levels) in require' <br>
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/bundler-1.1.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:66:in`each' 
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/bundler-1.1.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:66:in `block in require' <br>
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/bundler-1.1.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:55:in`each' 
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/bundler-1.1.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:55:in `require' <br>
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/bundler-1.1.5/lib/bundler.rb:119:in`require' 
    from /root/railsdev/simple_cms/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/railties-3.2.6/lib/rails/commands.rb:53:in`require' 
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/railties-3.2.6/lib/rails/commands.rb:53:in `block in <top (required)>' <br>
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/railties-3.2.6/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in`tap' 
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/railties-3.2.6/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `<top (required)>' <br>
    from script/rails:6:in`require' 
    from script/rails:6:in `'

How do i fix this?

 **rvm info gives the following result**

ruby-1.9.3-p194:

system:
    uname:       "Linux localhost.localdomain 2.6.32-220.el6.i686 #1 SMP Tue Dec 6 16:15:40 GMT 2011 i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux"
    bash:        "/bin/bash => GNU bash, version 4.1.2(1)-release (i386-redhat-linux-gnu)"
    zsh:         " => not installed"

rvm:
    version:      "rvm 1.14.7 (stable) by Wayne E. Seguin , Michal Papis  [https://rvm.io/]"
    updated:      "1 hour 22 minutes 29 seconds ago"

ruby:
    interpreter:  "ruby"
    version:      "1.9.3p194"
    date:         "2012-04-20"
    platform:     "i686-linux"
    patchlevel:   "2012-04-20 revision 35410"
    full_version: "ruby 1.9.3p194 (2012-04-20 revision 35410) [i686-linux]"

homes:
    gem:          "/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194"
    ruby:         "/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194"

binaries:
    ruby:         "/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/ruby"
    irb:          "/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/irb"
    gem:          "/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/gem"
    rake:         "/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/rake"

environment:
    PATH:         "/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin:/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/bin:/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin:/usr/local/rvm/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/root/bin"
    GEM_HOME:     "/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194"
    GEM_PATH:     "/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194:/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global"
    MY_RUBY_HOME: "/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194"
    IRBRC:        "/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/.irbrc"
    RUBYOPT:      ""
    gemset:       ""

Comment: this may help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6282307/execjs-and-could-not-find-a-javascript-runtime

Comment: rvm info gives the following result

Answer (score 0):

Install NodeJS and add the gem into the Gemfile. This should fix the runtime problem.

Answer (score 0):

Since Rails 3.1, a JavaScript runtime has been needed for development on Linux Ubuntu. It is not needed for Mac OS X or Windows.

For development on Linux Ubuntu, it’s best to install the Node.js server-side JavaScript environment:

sudo apt-get install nodejs

and set it in your $PATH.

If you don’t install Node.js, you’ll need to add this to the Gemfile for each Rails application you build:

gem 'therubyracer', '>= 0.9.9'

[source](http://railsapps.github.com/rails-3-2-example-gemfile.html)