# Cannot run rails server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, linux, ruby-on-rails-3

I am starting to learn Ruby on Rails but have been stuck at the basic installation part for 2 days now. I was following a tutorial which mentions starting the server with the `rails server` command.

Running this command, I get the following output:

```
$ rails server
/home/niranjan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/execjs-1.4.0/lib/execjs/runtimes.rb:51:in `autodetect': Could not find a JavaScript runtime. See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs for a list of available runtimes. (ExecJS::RuntimeUnavailable)
    from /home/niranjan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/execjs-1.4.0/lib/execjs.rb:5:in `<module:ExecJS>'
    from /home/niranjan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/execjs-1.4.0/lib/execjs.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/niranjan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/coffee-script-2.2.0/lib/coffee_script.rb:1:in `require'
    from /home/niranjan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/coffee-script-2.2.0/lib/coffee_script.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/niranjan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/coffee-script-2.2.0/lib/coffee-script.rb:1:in `require'
    from /home/niranjan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/coffee-script-2.2.0/lib/coffee-script.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/niranjan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/coffee-rails-3.2.2/lib/coffee-rails.rb:1:in `require'
    from /home/niranjan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/coffee-rails-3.2.2/lib/coffee-rails.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/niranjan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/bundler-1.1.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:68:in `require'
    from /home/niranjan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/bundler-1.1.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:68:in `block (2 levels) in require'
    from /home/niranjan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/bundler-1.1.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:66:in `each'
    from /home/niranjan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/bundler-1.1.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:66:in `block in require'
    from /home/niranjan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/bundler-1.1.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:55:in `each'
    from /home/niranjan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/bundler-1.1.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:55:in `require'
    from /home/niranjan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/bundler-1.1.5/lib/bundler.rb:119:in `require'
    from /home/niranjan/fourth_app/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/niranjan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/commands.rb:53:in `require'
    from /home/niranjan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/commands.rb:53:in `block in <top (required)>'
    from /home/niranjan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `tap'
    from /home/niranjan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `<top (required)>'
    from script/rails:6:in `require'
    from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

I have been having several different problems and I have done `rvm implode` and reinstall several times. I have the rvm scripts in the PATH variable.

```
$ rvm -v

rvm 1.15.7 (stable) by Wayne E. Seguin <wayneeseguin@gmail.com>, Michal Papis <mpapis@gmail.com> [https://rvm.io/]

 $ ruby -v
ruby 1.9.3p194 (2012-04-20 revision 35410) [x86_64-linux]


$ rails -v
Rails 3.2.8
```

I am using Linux Mint 12. Any help/suggestion would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this, it worked for me

Add following lines in your 'Gemfile' (Placed in directory created for Rails project)

> gem 'therubyracer'
>
> gem 'execjs'

and run this command in your terminal

> bundle install

Thats it..!! :)

Answer (score 3):

Do you have a JS runtime? I think it's required from Rails 3.1 onwards (for the asset pipeline). Check out this article: [Deploying a Rails 3.1 App Gotchas](http://merbist.com/2011/08/30/deploying-a-rails-3-1-app-gotchas/).

Try [installing node.js](https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/Installing-Node.js-via-package-manager).

It might also be related to this: [ExecJS and could not find a JavaScript runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6282307/execjs-and-could-not-find-a-javascript-runtime)

Comment: one can also use therubyracer in place of node.js. Simply add `gem 'therubyracer'` in your gem file and `bundle install` before starting `rails server`