# "Could not find a JavaScript runtime." during executing the refinerycms command

Tags: refinerycms

I am working on Ubuntu 12.04.

I am trying to create a new website with Refinery CMS.
I read [the official Getting Started guide](http://refinerycms.com/guides/getting-started), and executed the following command.

```
$ refinerycms rickrockstar
```

But I got the following error message:

```
Your bundle is complete! Use `bundle show [gemname]` to see where a bundled gem is installed.
        rake db:create
rake aborted!
Could not find a JavaScript runtime. See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs for a list of available runtimes.

(See full trace by running task with --trace)
    generate refinery:cms --fresh-installation
/home/jharai/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/execjs-1.4.0/lib/execjs/runtimes.rb:51:in `autodetect': Could not find a JavaScript runtime. See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs for a list of available runtimes. (ExecJS::RuntimeUnavailable)
        from /home/jharai/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/execjs-1.4.0/lib/execjs.rb:5:in `<module:ExecJS>'
        from /home/jharai/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/execjs-1.4.0/lib/execjs.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
        from /home/jharai/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/coffee-script-2.2.0/lib/coffee_script.rb:1:in `require'
        from /home/jharai/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/coffee-script-2.2.0/lib/coffee_script.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
        from /home/jharai/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/coffee-script-2.2.0/lib/coffee-script.rb:1:in `require'
        from /home/jharai/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/coffee-script-2.2.0/lib/coffee-script.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
        from /home/jharai/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/coffee-rails-3.2.2/lib/coffee-rails.rb:1:in `require'
        from /home/jharai/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/coffee-rails-3.2.2/lib/coffee-rails.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
        from /home/jharai/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/bundler-1.2.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:68:in `require'
        from /home/jharai/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/bundler-1.2.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:68:in `block (2 levels) in require'
        from /home/jharai/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/bundler-1.2.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:66:in `each'
        from /home/jharai/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/bundler-1.2.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:66:in `block in require'
        from /home/jharai/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/bundler-1.2.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:55:in `each'
        from /home/jharai/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/bundler-1.2.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:55:in `require'
        from /home/jharai/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/bundler-1.2.1/lib/bundler.rb:128:in `require'
        from /srv/samba/share/refinery2test/rickrockstar/config/application.rb:13:in `<top (required)>'
        from /home/jharai/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/commands.rb:24:in `require'
        from /home/jharai/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/commands.rb:24:in `<top (required)>'
        from script/rails:6:in `require'
        from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

I've pasted [the entire output](https://gist.github.com/3942771) on Gist because it was too long.

Strangely, I tried the same command some days before, and at that time everything worked fine.

Why does this happen?  How can I solve it?

Comment: I posted an issue with the cause of the problem.
https://github.com/refinery/refinerycms/issues/2001

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could `sudo apt-get install nodejs` or see this post [ExecJS and could not find a JavaScript runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6282307/execjs-and-could-not-find-a-javascript-runtime)

Answer (score 0):

To solve it I did:

- Run **refinerycms rickrockstar** - it will fail with exception you described
- Edit `rickrockstar/Gemfile` and uncomment `*gem 'therubyracer', :platforms => :ruby*` and save changes;
- Run **refinerycms rickrockstar** again
- Gemfile will have a conflict and ask if you want to *override* it. Answer no;
- Override other files with conflicts
- **cd rickrockstar**
- **rails s**