# Installing rails on PPC linux (lubuntu 12.04)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, linux, node.js, v8, powerpc

Ok. So I have an old PowerMac G5 and I decided to use it as a staging server.

I went along trying to do all the normal installing rails things, when I experienced this error.

```
Could not find a JavaScript runtime. See https://github.com/sstephenson/ExecJS (GitHub) for a list of available runtimes (ExecJS::RuntimeUnavailable).
```

[ExecJS and could not find a JavaScript runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6282307/execjs-and-could-not-find-a-javascript-runtime)

As far as I can tell, this is because there is no javascript runtime for ExecJS to call. People suggested installing Node-JS to fix the problem. This makes sense.

Turns out, Node, which requires the V8 javascript engine, which required ARM or i386, doesn't run on PPC.

So am I screwed, or is there another Javascript runtime I can use for rails. And how would I set that up?  Thanks.

Comment: Trying this could help? https://github.com/ic/v8-powerpc

Comment: That has been dead for 2 years it seems. As far as I can tell there was never any deployable code.

Comment: add to Gemfile `gem 'therubyracer', :platforms => :ruby` and run `bundle install`

Comment: I think therubyracer also uses V8.

after adding it to the gemfile, bundle install now tries to install libV8.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the PPC port of V8 actively developed by IBM folks:

https://github.com/andrewlow/v8ppc