# ruby tutorial to launch my app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

i'm just starting with an Unix based OS 
i installed RVM to do the same basic tutorial like windows(dos), but i get
an error, i tried to do the same work in root/user shell but is the same
when i run `rails server` i get this message:

```
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/execjs-2.0.1/lib/execjs/runtimes.rb:51:in `autodetect': Could not find a JavaScript runtime. See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs for a list of available runtimes. (ExecJS::RuntimeUnavailable)
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/execjs-2.0.1/lib/execjs.rb:5:in `<module:ExecJS>'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/execjs-2.0.1/lib/execjs.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/uglifier-2.2.1/lib/uglifier.rb:3:in `require'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/uglifier-2.2.1/lib/uglifier.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `require'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `block (2 levels) in require'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:70:in `each'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:70:in `block in require'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:59:in `each'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:59:in `require'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler.rb:132:in `require'
    from /home/raul/blog/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:76:in `require'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:76:in `block in <top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:73:in `tap'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:73:in `<top (required)>'
    from bin/rails:4:in `require'
    from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

i reviwed the gem command and dome problems was founded too. Execjs is installed several times in my machine, `root->user`. This is what i get with `gem check`:

```
json-1.8.0.gem has 12 problems
  ext/json/ext/generator/.RUBYARCHDIR.time:
    Extra file
  ext/json/ext/generator/Makefile:
    Extra file
  ext/json/ext/generator/generator.o:
    Extra file
  ext/json/ext/generator/generator.so:
    Extra file
  ext/json/ext/generator/siteconf20130920-14093-1b8hzo9.rb:
    Extra file
  ext/json/ext/parser/.RUBYARCHDIR.time:
    Extra file
  ext/json/ext/parser/Makefile:
    Extra file
  ext/json/ext/parser/parser.o:
    Extra file
  ext/json/ext/parser/parser.so:
    Extra file
  ext/json/ext/parser/siteconf20130920-14093-zefm93.rb:
    Extra file
  lib/json/ext/generator.so:
    Extra file
  lib/json/ext/parser.so:
    Extra file
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [ExecJS and could not find a JavaScript runtime](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6282307/execjs-and-could-not-find-a-javascript-runtime)

Comment: Is posible to fix that? how can i remove the duplicate code?"files/programs"?

Comment: @Hell0 - Try `gem pristine execjs`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add a JavaScript runtime to your Gemfile (for example, execJS): `gem 'execjs'`

Then, just run `bundle install` and it should work.

Comment: the machine says: `while executing gem ... (Gem::CommandLineError)                Unknown command execjs`

Comment: i tried to set up the envoirement variable, writing something like a mini path. i runed this "mini" typing `source <<myfile_path>>` then i can try to see the versions of gem rails, ruby, bundle, etc. But when i run `rails server` the whole lines above.

Comment: `require "execjs/module"
require "execjs/disabled_runtime"
require "execjs/external_runtime"
require "execjs/johnson_runtime"
require "execjs/mustang_runtime"
require "execjs/ruby_racer_runtime"
require "execjs/ruby_rhino_runtime"

module ExecJS
  module Runtimes
    Disabled = DisabledRuntime.new ` <<----this line can be changed by `Enable` or is a bad idea?

Comment: No, you are wrong. You just wrote the command `gem 'execjs'` in your terminal instead of adding the line `gem 'execjs'` to your Gemfile.

Comment: where i must add this line? in : `/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/execjs-2.0.1/lib/execjs/runtimes.rb`

Comment: update your original question with the contents of your gemfile

Comment: In /path/to/your/rails_app/Gemfile.rb .

Answer (score 1):

Install node

```
sudo apt-get install nodejs
```

followed by

```
gem install execjs
```

or just put `gem 'execjs'` in your gemfile.

EDIT: i'm editing my answer based on your edits and comments.

Comment: is installed, i read the git docs, i swear. `Unable to locate package nodejs`

Comment: `Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package nodejs` <--result