# ruby on rails error when running the server or generating something

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I successfully made a new rails project!

But when I try to generate something in a rails project or start rails server by typing `rails server` or creating a controller `rails g controller` I get the same error (I try to run bundle install before this; I have Rails 4.1.1) :

```
Warning: Running `gem pristine --all` to regenerate your installed gemspecs (and deleting then reinstalling your bundle if you use bundle --path) will improve the startup performance of Spring.
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/execjs-2.1.0/lib/execjs/runtimes.rb:51:in `autodetect': Could not find a JavaScript runtime. See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs for a list of available runtimes. (ExecJS::RuntimeUnavailable)
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/execjs-2.1.0/lib/execjs.rb:5:in `<module:ExecJS>'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/execjs-2.1.0/lib/execjs.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/uglifier-2.5.0/lib/uglifier.rb:3:in `require'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/uglifier-2.5.0/lib/uglifier.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `require'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `block (2 levels) in require'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/bundler/runtime.rb:70:in `each'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/bundler/runtime.rb:70:in `block in require'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/bundler/runtime.rb:59:in `each'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/bundler/runtime.rb:59:in `require'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/bundler.rb:132:in `require'
    from /home/abd/rorblog/blog/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/spring-1.1.3/lib/spring/application.rb:82:in `require'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/spring-1.1.3/lib/spring/application.rb:82:in `preload'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/spring-1.1.3/lib/spring/application.rb:140:in `serve'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/spring-1.1.3/lib/spring/application.rb:128:in `block in run'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/spring-1.1.3/lib/spring/application.rb:122:in `loop'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/spring-1.1.3/lib/spring/application.rb:122:in `run'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/spring-1.1.3/lib/spring/application/boot.rb:18:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from -e:1:in `<main>'
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [ExecJS and could not find a JavaScript runtime](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6282307/execjs-and-could-not-find-a-javascript-runtime)

Comment: no this is not my error :(

Comment: Take a close look at line 2 of the stacktrace you posted.

Comment: I know but I have other errors I have a problem with spring

Comment: Can you elaborate on the Spring problem?

Comment: Thank a lot bro I found the solution :D ; but i have now a routing error : " No route matches [GET] "/posts" " after generating a controller called posts ^_^ do you have any solution ?

Comment: post a separate question (remember to do some research first!). from the sounds of it, check your `routes.rb`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the `No route matches [GET] "/posts"` error, go to your `config/routes.rb` file and add this:

```
resources :posts
```

And I really encourage you to find a decent beginners tutorial or read the official manual to get to know Rails.