# jquery not working in rails

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I've read many pages about using jquery in rails and still can't seem to get it to work.

I have the 'jquery-rails' gem, and I installed.
I have the require statements in the application.js file.

Here is a test page I keep running:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <head>
<title><%= yield(:title)%></title>
<%= javascript_include_tag 'application','jquery', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true  %>
<%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
<%= csrf_meta_tags %>
<script>$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".bg-info").click(function(){
    $(this).hide();
});
 });</script>
</head>
<body>
<center>
<h1 class="bg-info"><%= yield(:title)%></h1>
</center>
</body>
</html>
```

But when I click on the "bg-info" text in the browser I get no response.

Comment: this is a stretch but in your `assets/javascripts/application.js`, do you have the following line: `//= require jquery` . Or maybe `bundle install`?

Comment: Can you try the following: `<%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>`. Remove `jquery` from that line, restart server, and try running

Comment: Try running `rake assets:clobber`. Maybe there are some asset cache problems

Comment: Open developer console in your browser and try to execute $(".bg-info").length (on that page where bg-info is located)

Comment: Can you include your `application.js` file?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's what you *should* have:

```
#app/assets/javascripts/application.js
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require_tree .

$(document).on("click", ".bg-info", function(e){
   $(this).hide();
});
```

Here's what I'd do for the layout (to test):

```
#app/views/layouts/application.html.erb
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
   <head>
       <title><%= yield(:title)%></title>
       <%= javascript_include_tag 'application','jquery', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true  %>
       <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
       <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
   </head>
   <body>
       <div class="bg-info"><%= yield(:title)%></div>
   </body>
</html>
```

If the above doesn't work out the box, you'll *probably* have an issue with your [development environment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deployment_environment#Development) (OS) -- most likely with [`ExecJS`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6282307/execjs-and-could-not-find-a-javascript-runtime).

To confirm this, you'll need to *debug* your [developer's console](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/debug/console/console-ui?hl=en#opening-the-console):

[image]

To access the dev console, `right-click > inspect element > console`.

This shows you any errors with your JS & your front-end environment. If any errors appear, they may tell you what the issue is.

If no errors appear, you should **[try installing NodeJS on your system](https://nodejs.org/en/)**, as this ensures Rails can use the appropriate JS executable.

Comment: devloper's console clue deserved +1