# rails generate devise:install error 1

Tags: ruby-on-rails

/home/leto/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.13.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:94:in `rescue in block (2 levels) in require': There was an error while trying to load the gem 'uglifier'.
Gem Load Error is: Could not find a JavaScript runtime. See https://github.com/rails/execjs for a list of available runtimes.
Backtrace for gem load error is:
/home/leto/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/execjs-2.7.0/lib/execjs/runtimes.rb:58:in`autodetect'
/home/leto/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/execjs-2.7.0/lib/execjs.rb:5:in `<module:ExecJS>'
/home/leto/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/execjs-2.7.0/lib/execjs.rb:4:in`'
/home/leto/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/uglifier-3.0.3/lib/uglifier.rb:5:in `require'
/home/leto/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/uglifier-3.0.3/lib/uglifier.rb:5:in`'
/home/leto/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.13.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:91:in `require'
/home/leto/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.13.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:91:in`block (2 levels) in require'
/home/leto/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.13.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:86:in `each'
/home/leto/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.13.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:86:in`block in require'
/home/leto/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.13.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:75:in `each'
/home/leto/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.13.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:75:in`require'
/home/leto/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.13.6/lib/bundler.rb:106:in `require'
/home/leto/rubyblog/config/application.rb:7:in`'
/home/leto/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/spring-2.0.0/lib/spring/application.rb:82:in `require'
/home/leto/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/spring-2.0.0/lib/spring/application.rb:82:in`preload'
/home/leto/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/spring-2.0.0/lib/spring/application.rb:143:in `serve'
/home/leto/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/spring-2.0.0/lib/spring/application.rb:131:in`block in run'
/home/leto/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/spring-2.0.0/lib/spring/application.rb:125:in `loop'
/home/leto/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/spring-2.0.0/lib/spring/application.rb:125:in`run'
/home/leto/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/spring-2.0.0/lib/spring/application/boot.rb:19:in `<top (required)>'
/home/leto/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in`require'
/home/leto/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
-e:1:in`'
Bundler Error Backtrace:
 (Bundler::GemRequireError)
    from /home/leto/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.13.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:90:in `block (2 levels) in require'
    from /home/leto/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.13.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:86:in`each'
    from /home/leto/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.13.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:86:in `block in require'
    from /home/leto/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.13.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:75:in`each'
    from /home/leto/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.13.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:75:in `require'
    from /home/leto/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.13.6/lib/bundler.rb:106:in`require'
    from /home/leto/rubyblog/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/leto/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/spring-2.0.0/lib/spring/application.rb:82:in`require'
    from /home/leto/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/spring-2.0.0/lib/spring/application.rb:82:in `preload'
    from /home/leto/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/spring-2.0.0/lib/spring/application.rb:143:in`serve'
    from /home/leto/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/spring-2.0.0/lib/spring/application.rb:131:in `block in run'
    from /home/leto/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/spring-2.0.0/lib/spring/application.rb:125:in`loop'
    from /home/leto/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/spring-2.0.0/lib/spring/application.rb:125:in `run'
    from /home/leto/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/spring-2.0.0/lib/spring/application/boot.rb:19:in`'
    from /home/leto/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /home/leto/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in`require'
    from -e:1:in `'

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ExecJS and could not find a JavaScript runtime](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6282307/execjs-and-could-not-find-a-javascript-runtime)

Comment: You’ve shared an error, but not a question. For help, see “[How to Ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)”. When seeking debugging help ("why am I getting this error?"), you must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or the error, and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. For help with this, see “[How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)”.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a question, but just an error stack. Please install nodejs and `gem install uglifier`. That's the one missing, the exact first line of your error stack

Answer (score 0):

install node.js [Node js download link](https://nodejs.org/en/download/package-manager/)