# Ubuntu Installation Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, installation

I had used below mentioned commands to install rails in ubuntu 12.10

```
sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install curl

\curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable

source ~/.rvm/scripts/rvm

rvm requirements

rvm install 1.9.3

rvm use 1.9.3 --default

rvm rubygems current

gem install rails
```

Every steps are doing good, but it works for terminal which we are installing rails. If we exit from the terminal and work on a new terminal then the following error occurs.

```
The program 'rails' can be found in the following packages: * rails * ruby-railties-3.2 Try: sudo apt-get install
```

I came through a solution that whenever I open an terminal I would run these cmd 
source ~/.rvm/scripts/rvm rvm --default use 1.9.3-p374

Can any one explain why these things happen??

Comment: Plese make your title more specific

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've installed Rails 3.2.9 on my machine with RVM. You can follow this steps:

1. Install RVM : `\curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable`
2. Reload shell configuration & test: `source ~/.rvm/scripts/rvm`
3. Install Ruby via RVM: `rvm install 1.9.2` or `rvm install 1.9.3`
4. Choose version Ruby after install: `rvm use 1.9.2` or `rvm use 1.9.3`
5. Ruby 1.9.2 and 1.9.3 support gem 1.8.25, so you'll install rails: gem install rails -v 3.2.9.

Done.

**Note** 
Reload shell: `source ~/.rvm/scripts/rvm` and choose version Ruby `rvm use 1.9.2` before work with projects.

Answer (score 1):

Did you include the init script into your bash_profile/bashrc?

[RVM installed by Ruby not working?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4911504/rvm-installed-by-ruby-not-working)