# RVM : ruby-2.0.0p451 is not installed

Tags: ruby, rvm

I'm trying to deploy a Rails app on a remote server. I installed RVM and ruby-2.0.0p451, **i can see that ruby is correctly installed** :

```
$ ruby --version
ruby 2.0.0p451 (2014-02-24 revision 45167) [armv6l-linux-eabihf]
```

When i cd into the app directory **RVM tells that this ruby version is not installed :**

```
$ cd /srv/www/my-app/releases/20140324211434
ruby-2.0.0p451 is not installed.
To install do: 'rvm install ruby-2.0.0p451'
```

Does anyone knows what i'm missing ?

---

Edit 1 :

Same error when i try to deploy with capistrano :

```
DEBUG [4bdd07e8] Command: cd /srv/www/photo-visualizer/releases/20140324211434 && ( RAILS_ENV=production ~/.rvm/bin/rvm default do bundle exec rake assets:precompile )
DEBUG [4bdd07e8]    ruby-2.0.0p451 is not installed.
DEBUG [4bdd07e8]    To install do: 'rvm install ruby-2.0.0p451'
```

Here is a copy of my [deploy.rb](https://gist.github.com/vdaubry/9750386#file-gistfile1-rb)

---

Edit 2 :

Same problem on my local machine :

I can see that ruby is installed, if i ask for the current version of ruby inside my app directory i get :

```
$ ruby --version
ruby 2.0.0p451 (2014-02-24 revision 45167) [x86_64-darwin12.5.0]
```

But when i cd inside the directory i get :

```
$ cd my-app/
ruby-2.0.0p451 is not installed.
To install do: 'rvm install ruby-2.0.0p451'
```

---

Edit 3 :

Here is a copy of my ~/.bashrc :

```
cat ~/.bashrc 
PATH=$PATH:$HOME/.rvm/bin # Add RVM to PATH for scripting
[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"
```

Comment: Please add your Capistrano deploy.rb file. Make sure to include the `:rvm_ruby_string`

Comment: I added a copy of my deploy.rb at the end

Comment: `set :rvm_ruby_string, :local # use the same ruby as used locally for deployment`. Do you have version 2.0.0p451 installed (and being currently used when trying to deploy) on both dev and production?

Comment: I added a comment, i installed ruby-2.0.0p451 and it seems to be correctly installed. But rvm says it cannot find it when i cd into my app. Does anyone know where could it be coming from ?

Comment: Refer to http://stackoverflow.com/a/4911570/1162491 and see if that resolves your issue.

Comment: No i have RVM set in my ~/.bashrc, i added more info about my rvm conf